# Alphabet triangle strikes again

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

## Task

Your task is to print this exact text:

```
A
BCD
EFGHI
JKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXY
ZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVW
XYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

## Specs

- You may do it in all-lowercase instead of all-uppercase.
- Trailing newlines at the end of the triangle is allowed.
- Trailing spaces after each line is allowed.
- You must print to STDOUT instead of outputting an array of strings.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Program with lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: What do you mean by "strikes again"? Was there another challenge you made like this?

Comment: @Peanut http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87496/alphabet-triangle

Comment: Seems fairly trivial do we really need (another) alphabet challenge?

Comment: It is a good challenge, but I think we have outstripped saturation of these alphabet challenges, nothing personal.

Comment: Actually looking for an alphabet challenge that the letter at a position cannot be calculated by simple expressions from its coordinates involving the `mod` function. May make one myself if I have time.

Answer (score 41):

## Vim, 29 bytes

```
:h<_↵↵↵y$ZZ26P0qqa↵♥βjllq25@q
```

Where `↵` represents the Return key, `♥` the Escape key, and `β` the Backspace key.

[image]

Comment: How do you always beat me to the vim answer on these? *Aargh* +1 anyway, I can't not upvote vim! :)

Comment: I still think you should use `␛` instead of `♥`. And `␈` instead of `β`. That's what these Unicode chars were made for. http://www.utf8icons.com/subsets/control-pictures

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, 65 bytes

```python
i=1
a=bytearray(range(65,91))*26
while a:print a[:i];a=a[i:];i+=2
```

Comment: I've changed the header to Python 2 because the code would not work in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
26RḤ’RØAṁY
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MjZS4bik4oCZUsOYQeG5gVk&input=)

#### How it works

```
26RḤ’RØAṁY  Main link. No Arguments.

26          Set the return value to 26.
  R         Range; yield [1, 2, ..., 25, 26].
   Ḥ        Unhalve; yield [2, 4, ..., 50, 52].
    ’       Decrement; yield [1, 3, ..., 49, 51].
     R      Range; yield [[1], [1, 2, 3], ..., [1, ..., 49], [1, ..., 51]].
      ØA    Yield the uppercase alphabet.
        ṁ   Mold the alphabet as the array of ranges. This repeats the uppercase
            letters over an over again, until all integers in the range arrays
            have been replaced with letters.
         Y  Join, separating by linefeeds.
```

Comment: Was "Double" called "Unhalve" back then? Also, `ṁ` is great!! [waiting to say congrats for 100k rep]

Comment: It's just a mnemonic. `H` is *halve* and `Ḥ` is its inverse (*unhalve*).

Comment: I just think of `/2` or `*2`, so it's "Halve" or "Double". That's why I was confused.

Comment: Also 10 bytes: [`27Ḷ²IRØAṁY`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#code=MjZS4bik4oCZUsOYQeG5gVk&input=)

Comment: Also 10 bytes: `51Rm2RØAṁY`

Answer (score 7):

### VBA Excel (80 bytes, 1742 bytes)

---

## Excel, 1742 bytes

Inspired by [the ugoren's creative answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87079/58742), I managed to find an Excel formula to create the pattern as shown in the OP.

```
=MID(REPT("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",26),(ROW()-1)^2+1,2*ROW()-1)
```

Paste this formula in cell A1, then drag all over range A1:A26.

The length of the formula is 67 bytes but you have to replicate it 26 times, so it's equal to 67*26=1742 bytes. Here is the output:

[image]

---

## Excel VBA, 80 bytes

Now it's possible we integrate Excel with VBA to automate the process and to save many bytes since VBA is built into most Microsoft Office applications, including Excel. Write and run the following code in the Immediate Window (use combination keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to display it in Visual Basic Editor):

```
[A1:A26]="=MID(REPT(""ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"",26),(ROW()-1)^2+1,2*ROW()-1)"
```

The program works by printing the Excel formula above to the range A1:A26. Unfortunately, both Excel and VBA have no built-in alphabet.

Comment: The column names look like a built-in alphabet to me. Use the first 26 column names.

Comment: @mbomb007 So what? I think it would be harder to use them instead of strings.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer So? My point was that there *is* a builtin alphabet.

Comment: @mbomb007 You said "Use the first 26 column names", which I perceived as "Use the first 26 column names instead of what you currently use", that's why I replied.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer It's a suggestion. Idk how many bytes it'd be.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 67 bytes

```
_#53=[]
s#i=take i s:drop i s#(i+2)
mapM putStrLn$cycle['A'..'Z']#1
```

A simple recursion over the length `i` of the line. In each step the next `i` chars are taken from an infinite repetition of the alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 90 bytes

```
StringRiffle[Flatten[Alphabet[]&~Array~26]~Internal`PartitionRagged~Range[1,51,2],"
",""]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes no input and returns a string as output. Golfing suggestions welcome. An example of what `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` does:

```
In[1]:= Internal`PartitionRagged[{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}, {2, 3, 1}]               

Out[1]= {{2, 3}, {5, 7, 11}, {13}}
```

Comment: Mathematica has a built-in for alphabet triangles?

Answer (score 4):

## C, 79 bytes

```c
main(i,j){for(i=0,j=1;i<676;i++){putchar(i%26+65);if(j*j==i+1){puts("");j++;}}}
```

My first answer in C \o/

Golfing suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: 62: `i;main(j){while(i<676)printf("\n%c"+(j*j^i++||!j++),i%26+65);}`

Comment: @xsot Thanks but I'm afraid that leading newlines are not allowed.

Comment: But there's no leading newline?

Comment: 60: `i;main(j){for(;j<27;j*j^++i||puts("",j++))putchar(i%26+65);}`

Comment: @immibis I guess I should post it then.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 37 bytes

```
26~l<:1aLc~j[@A:I],L~@nw
=:2%1,.#@l?,
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=MjZ-bDw6MWFMY35qW0BBOkldLEx-QG53Cj06MiUxLC4jQGw_LA&input=)

#### Explanation

- Main predicate:

  ```
  26~l         Let there be a list of 26 elements
  <            This list is an ascending list of integers
  :1aL         Apply predicate 1 to that list ; the resulting list of strings is L
  c            Concatenate the list of strings into one big string
  ~j[@A:I],    That big string is the result of juxataposing the alphabet I times to itself
  L~@n         Create a string which when splitted on line breaks results in L
  w            Write that string to STDOUT
  ```
- Predicate 1: used to generate variable strings of odd lengths.

  ```
  =            Assign a value to the Input
  :2%1,        That value must be odd
  .#@l?,       Output is a string of length Input
  ```

Comment: Finally you do an ascii-art challenge

Comment: @LeakyNun Would classify that as string manipulation more than ASCII art imo

Comment: Should I add that to the tag?

Comment: Nice use of the fact that the last line is the only line which ends in `Z` which is because `26` is square-free.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
perl -E '@b=(A..Z)x26;say splice@b,0,$#a+=2for@b'
```

Just the code:

```
@b=(A..Z)x26;say splice@b,0,$#a+=2for@b
```

An obvious shorter version unfortunately triggers an internal perl problem (Use of freed value in iteration):

```
say splice@b,0,$#a+=2for@b=(A..Z)x26
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 1492 bytes

```
    ^         ^
   / \       / \
  /set\     /do \
 ^-----^   ^-----^
/a\   ^-  /!\   /[\
---  ^-  ^---  ^---^
    ^-  /=\   ^-  / \
   ^-  ^---^  -^ /out\
  ^-  ^-  /a\ ^- -----^
 ^-  / \  ---/[\     / \
 -^ /51 \   ^---^   /chr\
 ^- -----  ^-  / \  -----^
 -^       ^-  /do \     / \
 ^-      ^-  ^-----^   /10 \
 -^     /[\  -^   ^-   -----
 ^-    ^---^  -^  -^ 
 -^   / \  -^ /c\ ^-  
 ^-  /set\ /[\--- -^    
^-  ^-----^---^   ^-
-^ /a\   /+\  -^  -^
^- ---  ^---^  -^  -^
-^     /a\ /2\ / \  -^
 -^    --- ---/set\  -^
  -^         ^-----^ ^-
   -^       /c\   /a\-^
    -^      ---   --- -^
     -^               /[\
      -^             ^---^
       -^           ^-   -^
       /]\         / \    -^
      ^---^       /set\    -^ 
     ^-   -^     ^-----^    -^
    / \   ^-    /c\   /-\    -^
   /set\ ^-     ---  ^---^    -^
  ^-----^-          /c\ /1\    -^
 /b\   / \          --- ---    /]\
 ---  / -1\                   ^---^
      -----                  ^-  / \
                            / \ /out\
                           /set\-----^
                          ^-----^    -^
                         /b\   /?\    -^
                         ---  ^---^   / \
                             /!\  -^ /chr\
                            ^---  /+\-----^
                           /=\   ^---^   /+\
                          ^---^ /b\ /1\ ^---^
                         /b\ / \--- ---/ \ /b\
                         ---/25 \     /65 \---
                            -----     -----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRJbsMwDLzrFew5MFgHSG9FH1JWQDYgPQQpkvTQ17tcJTmLLcCJLJJDzlD0z995ffzedZftYX/cDwPwyhArJ/5BIH/lHR/gZX@1E9yd5CR3siTKdwnXpG/s8iI7/KTEBjvKvhNHCLf3EqA5iiOj8oOn36scZ4cQfP73bBEHcsCpaq0SuuqBoIABbg9nrdmiYRSsaF3wV4tQrIByBE15jtm/ejYwsgAuBzhsRFZK8niIZedSt8oKnJDKzGBSpUGnJm1RPEmk6o0LCuhk/G4SpqiQ3XFJkTgq10SsoPVXu9M1d8HpckZoDFK0Ino3w6DZDdIMLRaEUAkemerduLWZosWGX1TRrE/FGAqpLa6sit4AjZjVaIS4joVg16AbnN@FVmZ3iBY1VBkE@wKBGxoNVhXfWSXbI3Q9wf1qBfJrfO9SZunpkgJitJ47CdmYjafrXsPHYEb8g@YcR6rO8bCvjE6QDjdM16mTMsuofJO8hgXN0M/KTrqcp6HVDSjGTZqwoUkpcLmKr9DbSiMnSdYrobth@Ac)

Why? Why not?

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
jtc*G26*Rd26
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jtc%2aG26%2aRd26&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 <s>82 88</s>

EcmaScript 6 required just to save 1 byte using a template string literal for newline.

```js
for(i=r=l=o='';l+52;r++||(r=l-=2,o+=`
`))o+=(i++%26+10).toString(36);alert(o)
```

*Less golfed*

```js
for(i = r = l = o = '';
    l + 52;
    r++ || (r = l -= 2, o += `\n`))
  o += (i++ % 26 + 10).toString(36);
alert(o);
```

**Test**

```js
for(i=r=l=o='';l+52;r++||(r=l-=2,o+=`
`))o+=(i++%26+10).toString(36);alert(o)
```

Comment: \o/ an ES6 answer I can run in my browser

Comment: I stole your .toString(36) logic...now you have to beat 80 bytes!!

Comment: Ahh I concede, I can't think of any way to beat this with my library. Thanks for the challenge!

Comment: [69](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPTNt9WXd0608bM3MxaM1/bViNTW1vVyEzb0EBTryQ/uKQoMy9dw9hMUzs6gSshOlNLS89U1TA21roAKFGika/5/z8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
Cİ1ṠṁK…"AZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/nIBsOHOxc83Nno/ahhmZJj1P//AA)

#### Explanation

```
Cİ1ṠṁK…"AZ
      …"AZ    Get the alphabet
   ṠṁK        Replace each letter with the whole alphabet
C             Cut the resulting string into lines with lengths
 İ1            equal to the list of odd numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 129 bytes

```
z=1,i=0,g=a=>{b=0,c="";while(a+a-1>b){c+='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split``[i>26?i=0:i++];b++}console.log(c)};while(z<26)g(z++)
```

Comment: Using the spread operator could save you *3 bytes*: `[...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']` instead of `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split\`\``.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 14 bytes

```
G26*WDoh<
Ko>D
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=G26%2aWDoh%3C%0AKo%3ED&warnings=0)

Answer (score 2):

## Go, 133 bytes

```
package main
import S "strings"
func main(){s:=S.Repeat("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXXYZ",26)
for i:=1;s!="";i+=2{println(s[:i]);s=s[i:]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>112 109 95 79</s> 77 bytes

This will also work with **Octave**, you can try [online here](http://octave-online.net).

```
a=['' 65:90 65:90]';j=0;for i=1:2:52;b=circshift(a,j);j=j-i;disp(b(1:i)');end
```

So after some major changes, I've saved a further <s>14</s> 32 bytes. This one is getting to be much more like the length I would have expected from MATLAB. I've left the old version below as it is substantially different.

```
a=['' 65:90 65:90]';        %Create 2 copies of the upper case alphabet
j=0;                        %Initialise cumulative sum
for i=1:2:52;               %For each line length
    b=circshift(a,j);       %Rotate the alphabet string by the cumulative offset
    j=j-i;                  %Update cumulative negative sum of offsets.
    disp(
         b(1:i)'            %Extract first 'line length' characters from rotated alphabet.
               );           %Display next line (disp adds newline automatically)
end
```

---

**Original version:**

```
a=['' repmat(65:90,1,26)];c=cumsum(1:2:51);disp(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(s,f)[a(s:f) 10],[1,c(1:25)+1],c,'Un',0)))
```

Wow that one ended up being longer than I thought it would. I'll see if I can't knock a few bytes off it.

An ungolfed version to explain:

```
a=['' repmat(65:90,1,26)]; %Create 26 copies of the upper case alphabet
c=cumsum(1:2:51);          %Calculate the end index of each row in the above array, by cumulatively summing the length of each line
disp(
     cell2mat(
              arrayfun(@(s,f)
                             [a(s:f) 10], %Extract the part of the alphabet and insert a new line.
                                         [1,c(1:25)+1],c, %start index is the previous end of line plus 1. End index is as calculated by cumsum.
                       'Un',0 %The returned values are not all the same length
                       )   %Do this for each line
              )            %Convert back to a matrix now new lines inserted
     )                     %And display it
```

---

**Acknowledgements**

- 3 bytes saved - thanks @LuisMendo

Answer (score 2):

### XPath 3.0 (and XQuery 3.0), 84 bytes

```
codepoints-to-string((0 to 25)!(subsequence(((1 to 26)!(65 to 90)),.*.+1,2*.+1),10))
```

Explanation:

`(1 to 26)!(65 to 90)` is the alphabet 26 times

`(0 to 25)!(subsequence(XX, start, len),10)` takes 26 subsequences of this, each followed by newline

`subsequence(X, .*.+1, 2*.+1)` takes successive subsequences with start position and length: (1, 1), (2, 3), (5, 5), (10, 9) etc.

`codepoints-to-string()` turns Unicode codepoints into characters

Comment: Bravo. I thought I knew what XQuery was. Turns out I had no idea.

Comment: I doubt that many of the posts here tell you much about the language they are written in.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```
26.times{|i|puts ([*?A..?Z]*26)[i*i,i*2+1]*""}
```

See it on ideone: http://ideone.com/3hGLB0

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E (alternate) 15 bytes

```
A2×52µ¼D¾£,¾¼FÀ
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QTLDlzUywrXCvETCvsKjLMK-wrxGw4A&input=)

Explanation:

```
A2×              # push a string containing a-za-z
   52µ           # Loop the rest of the program until counter = 52
      ¼          # increment counter (it's 0 initially)
       D         # Duplicate the alpha string on the stack
        ¾£       # Replace alpha with alpha[0..counter]
          ,      # Pop the substring and print it
           ¾¼FÀ  # rotate the alpha string left counter++ times.
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>120</s> <s>115</s> 111 bytes

```
v=c();for(i in 1:26){v=c(v,c(rep(LETTERS,26)[(sum((b=seq(1,51,2))[1:i-1])+1):sum(b[1:i])],"\n"))};cat(v,sep="")
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
a=rep(LETTERS,26)
b=seq(1,51,2)
v=vector()

for(i in 1:26)
    {
    v=c(v,c(a[(sum(b[1:i-1])+1):sum(b[1:i])],"\n"))
    }

cat(v,sep="")
```

Basically, `b` is the vector of the odd numbers between `1` and `51`, thus giving the length of each line. Obviously, the `sum` function *sums* the numbers of this vector, and gives the starting and ending indexes.

*-5 bytes* thanks to @plannapus !
*-4 bytes* thanks to @plannapus !

Comment: arf, sorry I didn't see that earlier, but since you're only using `a` once you don't actually need to define it, meaning you can shave a couple more bytes: `b=seq(1,51,2);v=c();for(i in 1:26){v=c(v,c(rep(LETTERS,26)[(sum(b[1:i-1])+1):sum(b[1:i])],"\n"))};cat(v,sep="")` works.

Comment: @plannapus Silly me ! Thanks again ! I also integrated the `b=seq` part in the main body, so it's even *less* readable !

Answer (score 2):

## R, <strike>81 73 65</strike> 63 bytes

A simple `for` loop approach. Repeat the alphabet 26 times and loop through a sliding index range that is calculated using `(i^2-2*i+2):i^2`.

```
for(i in 1:26)cat(rep(LETTERS,26)[(i^2-2*i+2):i^2],"\n",sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 123 bytes

```
@set s=
@for /l %%i in (1,2,51)do @call set s=%%s%%ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&call echo %%s:~0,%%i%%&call set s=%%s:~%%i%%
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>31</s> <s>25</s> 23 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Requires `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems.

```apl
↑(∊1,¨0⍴¨⍨2×⍳26)⊂676⍴⎕A
```

`676⍴⎕A` cycle the letters to get 676 of them

`(`...`)⊂` split on ones in

`⍳26` zero through 25; {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 25}

`2×` multiply them by 2, {0, 2, 4, 6, ..., 50}

`0⍴¨⍨` generate zero-sequences of such lengths; {}, {0}, {0, 0}, etc.

`1,¨` prepend one to each sequence; {1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, etc.

`∊` flatten; {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0}

`↑` stack the strings

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395io%u21900%20%u22C4%20%u2191%28%u220A1%2C%A80%u2374%A8%u23682%D7%u237326%29%u2282676%u2374%u2395A&run)

-6 thanks to @jimmy23013

Comment: `26 51⍴(,↑1⍴¨⍨¯1+2×⍳26)\676⍴⎕A`

Comment: `↑(∊1,1,¨0⍴¨⍨2×⍳25)⊂676⍴⎕A`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
26FA26×N>n£NnF¦},
```

**Explanation**

```
26F                 # for N in range(0, 26) do
   A26×             # the alphabet repeated 26 times
       N>n£         # take (N+1)^2 letters
           NnF¦}    # throw away the first N^2 letters
                ,   # print with newline
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MjZGQTI2w5dOPm7Co05uRsKmfSw&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 17 bytes

Takes the lowercase alphabet 26 times, prints `1,3,5,...,(2*n+1)` at a time. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=w7psw7oqacO6bGDilZx14pWfzqMpMuKVlmBu&input=)

**Edit:** Many thanks and -4 bytes to Leaky Nun and his suggestions.

```
úlú*iúl`╜u╟Σ)2╖`n
```

**Ungolfing:**

```
úl    Pushes 26 (the length of the lowercase alphabet).
ú*    26 * the lowercase alphabet.
i     Flatten the string.
úl    Pushes 26.
  `     Start function.
  ╜u    Push register 0 (default: 0) and increment (call it len, from now on)
  ╟     Take len elements from the stack
  Σ     sum() into a string.
  )     Rotate the string to the bottom of the stack.
  2╖    Add 2 to register 0.
  `     End function.
n     Run the above function (26) times.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 18 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/)

[`↑2{⍺↓⍵⍴⎕a}/×⍨0,⍳26`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u21912%7B%u237A%u2193%u2375%u2374%u2395a%7D/%D7%u23680%2C%u237326&run)

Comment: 18 bytes or 18 characters? To encode these 18 characters as 18 bytes, you need a custom character encoding; and we could compress any of the solutions if we choose our character encoding carefully enough.

Comment: @MichaelKay [When can APL characters be counted as 1 byte each?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9428/12012)

Comment: Will you explain this, or shall I?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Using external library - Enumerable) (<s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> 80 bytes)

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

```
(z=_.Range)(0,26).WriteLine(x=>z(x*x,2*x+1).Write("",y=>(y%26+10).toString(36)))
```

Code explanation: Create range of ints 0 to 25, and for each write a new line according to the predicate. For each line, create a range of ints starting at the square of the current int, for a count of 2x+1. Then take that range, and join it into a string delimited by nothing where each int is casted to the String represented by the int ascii code

[image]

Comment: I highly doubt that the javascript answer without the library would be longer than this.

Comment: [Exactly](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90575/48934).

Comment: Ill have to optimize my answer ;)

Comment: 86 bytes, bring it on vanilla JS!

Comment: Well, I already had borrowed your %26. Now can you do better?

Comment: Ahhhh I dont think I can beat 77!! Ill look later!

Comment: You should switch to lodash or something. I'm pretty sure lodash will give you much more leverage.

Comment: What do you mean "more leverage"? Just curious how so

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 68 bytes

```
$a=-join(65..90|%{[char]$_})*26;26..1|%{$a=$a.Insert($_*$_,"`n")};$a
```

The section before the first semicolon produces a string containing 26 copies of the uppercase alphabet. The next section injects linebreaks at the index of each square number (working backward so I don't have to account for the shifting). Finally, the `$a` at the end just shoves that string variable onto PowerShell's equivalent of `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL, 129 bytes

USE MASTER in the beginning of the script is to ensure that the query is run in the master database which is default for many users(not counting bytes for that).

**Golfed:**

```
USE MASTER

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLICATE('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',26),number*number+1,number*2+1)FROM spt_values WHERE number<26and'P'=type
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
USE MASTER

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLICATE('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',26),number*number+1,number*2+1)
FROM spt_values
WHERE number<26and'P'=type
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527267/alphabet-triangle-strikes-again)**

**[Fiddle for older version using xml path](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527174/alphabet-triangle-strikes-again)**

Answer (score 1):

## Rexx, <del>74</del> 72 bytes

```
i=1;m=1;do 26;say substr(copies(xrange('A','Z'),26),i,m);i=i+m;m=m+2;end
```

Ungolfed:

```
i=1
m=1
do 26
  say substr(copies(xrange('A','Z'),26),i,m)
  i=i+m
  m=m+2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 60 bytes

```
i;main(j){for(;j<27;j*j^++i||puts("",j++))putchar(i%26+65);}
```

Comment: `puts` only takes one argument.  (Some undefined behaviour is permitted in codegolf normally but this is a bit too far outside the usual lanes)

Comment: @M.M Undefined behaviour is exploited all the time. The rule is that a submission is valid as long as it works in some compiler, otherwise we would have to explicitly rule out a long list of exceptions. This code works in gcc so it's a valid submission.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <strike>122</strike> 108 bytes

```
void a(){int a=65,l,i;for(l=1;l<53;l+=2){for(i=0;i<l;i++){std::putchar(a);a>90?a=65:a++;}std::cout<<'\n';}}
```

First time trying my hand at one of these, so it'll probably be super inefficient.

It creates an integer `a`, then enters a for loop with `l` representing the number of characters in a line (stopping when reaching the maximum amount, 53) Inside the loop, it enters another loop based on the value of `l`, which prints `a` to the console, then either increments it or sets it back to `A`. After completing that loop, it prints a `newline` to extend the pyramid.

EDIT: Improved by changing `a` from a char to an int, which eliminates the need for `(int)a++` among other things and saves precious bytes. Also replaced the while statement with an equivalent for.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 111 bytes

```
void a(){int c=65,i,j;for(i=0;i<26;i++){for(j=0;j<=2*i;j++){std::cout<<(char)c;c++;if(c==91)c=65;}std::cout<<'\n';}}
```

First try at one of these.
Uses an int "c" to record which letter it needs to print at any given time. Once "c" passes 90 ('Z') it gets reset to 65 ('A'). Prints the pyramid using for loops.

Comment: Nice answer! You could do `if(c<92)c=65` to take one byte off, and you might also be able to do `int a()` instead of `void a()`, but I'm not positive if that works without the return. Other than that, I think you need to include `#include <iostream>` in your byte count.

Comment: I believe you meant `if(c>90)c=65`, but thanks for the suggestion, it's a good idea. Also, I guess I'll include it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>76</s> 69 bytes

```
for(;$i<26&&$a.=join(range(A,Z));)echo substr($a,$i**2,1+2*$i++)."
";
```

- Create 26 alphabet (more than enough) and contactenate them in $a
- loop for i < 26
- display $a substring start i^2, end 2*i+1

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 153 Bytes

```
using b=System.Console;class a{static void Main(){int i=0,j=0,k=0;while(i<26){b.Write((char)(65+j));j++;j%=26;k++;if(2*i+1==k){b.WriteLine();i++;k=0;}}}}
```

Compile using Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 or later. (Written using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.)

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
A27×26L·<£»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/)

Explanation:

```
A27×         # Push the alphabet repeated 27 times
    26L      # Push [1, 2, ..., 26]
       ·     # Multiply by 2 [2, 4, ..., 52]
        <    # Subtract 1 [1, 3, ..., 51]
         £   # Repeated slice
          »  # Join by newlines
             # Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 72 bytes

Anonymous function that takes  no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For J=1 To 51
For K=1 To J
I=I Mod 26+1
Print Chr(64+I)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0jBy9ZQISRfwdSQC8TzhvC8uDxtPRV881MUjMy0DbkCijLzShScM4o0zEy0PTW5/FIrSiCC1mD2//8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 25 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1(0,+\1+2*!25)_676#.Q.A;
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)-1(0,+\1+2*!25)_676#.Q.A;
A
BCD
EFGHI
JKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXY
ZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVW
XYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**Explanation:**

Slice up a list of the alphabet repeated 26 times...

```
-1(0,+\1+2*!25)_676#.Q.A; / the solution
-1                      ; / print to STDOUT and swallow return
                    .Q.A  / uppercase alphabet A-Z
                676#      / 676 take from the alphabet
               _          / cut at indexes given by left
  (           )           / do this stuff together
           !25            / range 0..24
         2*               / multiply by 2
       1+                 / add 1
     +\                   / calculate sums of list
   0,                     / prepend 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 14 bytes

```
V26:*26G^N2^hN2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V26%3A*26G%5EN2%5EhN2&debug=0)

```
V26             - for N in range(26):
        ^N2     -   N**2
   :*26G        -  (alphabet*26)[^:V]
           ^hN2 -   (N+1)**2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 109 bytes

```
for(int i=0,c=-1,j;i<26;i++,System.out.println())for(j=0;j<1+2*i;j++)System.out.print((char)(65+(c=++c%26)));
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```
for (int i = 0, c = -1, j; i < 26; i++, System.out.println())
    for (j = 0; j < 1 + 2 * i; j++) System.out.print((char) (65 + (c = ++c % 26)));
```

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoMwEAC/EgQhISoi1Eua/qAnj6WHbaxl0xjFrGIR355a6GGYy4yFBXLbvqNxEAK7buP8cGhYIKBDy4At6wE9b2hC/7rdQWxxgYmtuvkEevbFMJPqhomjJ4a6zMyBVXiuarUW4zGR81yIX2I1SilR2Ty/lMpoKU1a1eKfdTxJTZLVJ2mEivsevw "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
úl`╜²1╖╜²;ú*Ht`na
```

**Ungolfing:**

```
úl    Pushes 26 (the length of the lowercase alphabet).
  `     Start function
  ╜²    Push register 0 (default: 0) and square. Call this a.
  1╖    Increment register 0.
  ╜²;   Push register 0, square and duplicate. Call this b.
  ú*    b times the lowercase alphabet. Call this repeated_alphabet.
  Ht    Get repeated_alphabet[:b][a:]
  `     End function.
n     Run the above function (26) times.
a     Invert the stack.
      Print the stack implicitly with newlines.
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=w7psYOKVnMKyMeKVluKVnMKyO8O6Kkh0YG5h&input=)

Answer (score 0):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 59 bytes

```
<v01'5'&0
+>    :@@:@$-?!v$&:d2*%'A'+o1+&1
 ^0;?=}:{:+2oa~<
```

This increments one item for each letter, another for how many letters in the current row, and checks that one to a constant to halt the program after the last line of 53 characters

[Try it online](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/Sn9QAvLirsJbBApiy)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6: 51 bytes

```
say .join for (|("A".."Z")xx*).rotor(1,3...51)[^26]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6: 50 bytes

Regex based solution:

```
.put for (("A".."Z").join x 26)~~m:g/.**{1+2*$++}/
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 83 bytes

```
[print("".join([chr((i%26)+97)for i in range(j*j,(j+1)*(j+1))]))for j in range(26)]
```

My first golfing experience.

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, 81 bytes

```
b=char('A'+(1:26)-1)';b=repmat(b,1,26);
for j=1:26
disp(b((j-1)*(j-1)+1:j*j))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 160 bytes

```
(let p((n 65)(t 0)(x 0))(when(> n 90)(set! n 65))(when(> x t)(set! t(+ 2 t))
(set! x 0)(displayln""))(when(< t 51)(display(integer->char n))(p(+ 1 n)t(+ 1 x))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (let loop ((n 65)
             (t 0)
             (x 0))
    (when (> n 90)
      (set! n 65))
    (when (> x t)
      (set! t (+ 2 t))
      (set! x 0)
      (displayln ""))
    (when (< t 51)
        (display (integer->char n))
        (loop (add1 n) 
              t 
              (add1 x)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
A
BCD
EFGHI
JKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXY
ZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVW
XYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

15 bytes of code, +1 for `-n` flag.

```
zX26^@(1,27)**2
```

[Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=elgyNl5AKDEsMjcpKioy&input=&args=LW4)

Explanation:

```
zX26             Lowercase alphabet, repeated 26 times
    ^@           Split at these indices:
       1,27        Range(1,27), i.e. numbers 1 through 26
      (    )**2    Square each number
                 Autoprint the resulting list, joined on newlines due to -n
```

---

My first solution is longer, but I think it's pretty cute:

```
L26P(zy,Y++++v+y)
```

Explanation:

```
L26               Loop 26 times:
      y             y is initially "", which is 0 in numeric context
       ,            Range from y to the following value:
         ++++v        v is initially -1; increment it twice (so it goes 1, 3, 5, ...)
        Y     +y      Add previous y to new v and yank result into y for next iteration
    (z          )   Use that range to get a slice from the lowercase alphabet (with
                    cyclical indexing)
   P                Print the slice (with trailing newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 139 bytes

```
(let((a"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))(do((n 3(+ n 2))(i 0 j)(j 1(+ j n))(b a(format()"~a~a"b a)))((= n 55))(format t"~a~%"(subseq b i j))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNDsIgEIRfZUNiMsSLP@nRh1laqiCFtlC1PfTVcY17mvm@zLbB5bFWBFsAVmzazvb3h/PPMMQ0TnMuy@v9WTelNboERLriSJEu0h2dyGt4OgvyFAUZYvRpHrhAq513VkK0CNxk1DSS/prKTx8U8mKynciQk19ytX4B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 63 bytes

Long live BASIC.

```vb
For J=1To 51
For K=1To J
I=Mod(I,26)+1
?Chr$(64+I);
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SMHL1jAkX8HUkAvE8QZzvLg8bX3zUzQ8dYzMNLUNueydM4pUNMxMtD01rbn8UitKuOzB1P//AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 68 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

That pesky `Chr$(...)` function is forcing me to use `Left$(...,1)` again.

```
0ForI=1To51:ForJ=1ToI:K=KMod26+1:?Left$(Chr$(64+K),1);:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNPWMCTf1NAKyPQCMT2tvG29ffNTjMy0Da3sfVLTSlQ0nDOKVDTMTLS9NXUMNa2t/FIrSrys7MG05///AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 136 bytes

Declared `Sub`routine that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Dim I,J,K,S
For J=1To 51
S=""
For K=1To J
I=I Mod 26+1
S+=Chr$(64+I)
Next
Console.WriteLine(S)
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETv@xVL8VBJKlS0t5yqQlLrJYLn1gYMtFlIU/HvY6ieBt5jmHnbeenGou9m@yycCcVEjmJsaVhGgy3opce2sw5OdkLJFW@4hgt5VKK8Ex5L0CLLVtKsRIEUElMf9xVLlon65Td5dWByCzfzCVCTm2k0u4e3wVytM7n@m7MbMA2u@XsQ4xc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 9 bytes

```
kA₅ẋ:żd‹ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwia0HigoXhuos6xbxk4oC54bqHIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### How?

```
kA₅ẋ:żd‹ẇ
kA        # Push the uppercase alphabet
  ₅       # Push the length without popping (26)
   ẋ      # Repeat it that many times
    :ż    # Duplicate and get range [1, length]
      d   # Double each
       ‹  # Decrement each
        ẇ # Split the repeated alphabet into chunks of that sizez
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
A26×ā·<£»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0cjs8PQjjYe22xxafGj3//8A)

Outputs a zillion trailing newlines, but whatever.

Answer (score -1):

## C#, 164 bytes

```c#
void a(){int i=0;Console.Write(String.Join("\n",Enumerable.Range(0,26).Select(n=>new string(Enumerable.Range(0,n*2+1).Select(m=>(char)(97+(i++)%26)).ToArray()))));}
```

Comment: I believe `"\n"` is enough instead of `"\r\n"`

Comment: You need to count `using System;` and `using System.Linq;`

Comment: no i do not need to count them, theyre default packages. im getting sick of this remark

Comment: @downrep_nation If you don't want to count them, you'll need to use fully-qualified class names.

Comment: Actually, it seems like you do need to include `using System`, since otherwise I get an error about `Console` not existing in the current context.

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/do-i-need-to-use-imports-or-can-i-call-a-class-explicity About java but the result is the same, either fully qualify them or include the namespaces