# Alphabet Diamond

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

You've seen the amazing [alphabet triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87496/alphabet-triangle?s=1%7C2.3157), the [revenge of the alphabet triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90497/alphabet-triangle-strikes-again) and now it's time for the revenge of the revenge of the alphabet triangle!

**Introducing...**

***THE ALPHABET DIAMOND!***

Your task is to output this exact text, lowercase/uppercase does not matter, though newlines do:

```
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedc
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfe
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgf
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjih
ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkji
jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkj
klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlk
lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponml
mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponm
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpon
opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpo
pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqp
qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrq
rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsr
stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvuts
tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvut
uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvu
vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwv
wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxw
xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyx
yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazy
zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaz
yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazy
xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyx
wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxw
vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwv
uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvu
tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvut
stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvuts
rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsr
qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrq
pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqp
opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpo
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpon
mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponm
lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponml
klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlk
jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkj
ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkji
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjih
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgf
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfe
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedc
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb
```

### This is code-golf, lowest bytecount wins.

**Rules:**

1. Standard loopholes are disallowed.
2. `a` must be the center of the alphabet diamond.

Comment: Nice challenge. I personally think it would make more sense if the corners were `a` and the center was `z`

Comment: @ETHproductions I wanted to make it harder for the golfing languages who can push the alphabet ;). Though I doubt it's much harder.

Comment: @carusocomputing A left rotate would do it. For example, `.<` would do it in Pyth: `.<S5 1` would result in `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`. It is the same as `.<[1 2 3 4 5)1`. Not sure for the diamond, though.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer I realize, there are some smarter ways to do it too, like collapsing the shift in a do-while. The diamond itself should require shifting, so there are ways to combine the initial shift in the actual diamond iterations as well. It was an intentional part of the challenge to see who optimized their looping.

Comment: @carusocomputing I meant about `b` being the initial letter instead of `a`. Of course shifting is vital too.

Comment: @carusocomputing huh?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
A27FÀDûˆ}¯û»
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=QTI3RsOARMO7y4Z9wq_Du8K7&input=)

**Explanation**

```
A              # push alphabet
 27F           # 27 times do
    À          # rotate alphabet left
     Dû        # create a palendromized copy
       ˆ       # add to global list
        }      # end loop
         ¯     # push global list
          û    # palendromize list
           »   # merge list on newline
               # implicit output
```

Comment: Could probably save a byte using registers and the g to calc the length of the alphabet instead of duping it.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Unless I'm doing it wrong (feel free to educate me if that is the case) I ended up at 13 doing that. I did manage to save a byte with the global list though.

Comment: `A©gF®À©û})û»` is what I was thinking. By no means are you ever doing it wrong! I've learned all I know from watching you heh. The global list is the same basic idea.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Yeah, with `ƒ` instead of `F` that would indeed be 12. Nice!

Comment: Now you're tied with me. :3

Comment: @Oliver: Indeed! And with 2 different approaches in the same language :)

Answer (score 29):

## Vim, <s>62</s>, 60 keystrokes

```
:se ri|h<_<cr>jjYZZPqqx$pYpq26@qdjyH:g/^/m0<cr>VP:%norm DPA<C-v><C-r>"<C-v><esc>x<cr>
```

Drawing on inspiration from [Lynn's awesome vim answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87010/31716) to take the idea of stealing the alphabet from the help docs.

You can watch it happen in real time as I struggle to remember the right sequence of keystrokes!

[image]

Note that this gif is *slightly* outdated because it produces the wrong output, and I haven't gotten around to re-recording it yet.

Comment: I tried this program and got [this](https://pastebin.com/a08Zxwj4).

Comment: Pls rerecord ty

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
2Y226Zv27Zv!+)
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MlkyMjZadjI3WnYhKyk&input=)

```
2Y2     % Push string 'abc...z'
26Zv    % Push symmetric range [1 2 ... 25 26 25 ... 2 1]
27Zv    % Push symmetric range [1 2 ... 25 26 27 26 25 ... 2 1]
!       % Transpose into a column
+       % Addition with broadcast. Gives a matrix of all pairwise additions:
        % [  2  3 ... 26 27 26 ...  3  2
             3  4 ... 27 28 27 ...  4  3
             ...
            27 28 ... 51 52 51 ... 28 27
            28 29 ... 52 53 52 ... 29 28
            27 28 ... 51 52 51 ... 28 27
             ...
             2  3 ... 26 27 26 ...  3  2 ]
)       % Index modularly into the string. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 129 Bytes

```
for(;++$i<27;)$o.=($s=($f=substr)($r=join(range(a,z)),$i,26-$i)).$t.strrev($s.$t=$f($r,0,$i))."\n";echo$o.$f($o,0,51).strrev($o);
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '(' on line 1` Which php version?

Comment: @Tschallacka PHP > 7 before you can write  `for($f=substr;` and `$f($r=join(range(a,z)),$i,26-$i))` instead of `($f=substr)($r=join(range(a,z)),$i,26-$i))` to avoid the error

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 75 bytes

```
g=(++)<*>reverse.init 
unlines$g$g.take 26.($cycle['a'..'z']).drop<$>[1..27]
```

How it works:

```
g=(++)<*>reverse.init    -- helper function that takes a list and appends the
                         -- reverse of the list with the first element dropped, e.g.
                         -- g "abc"  -> "abcba"

             <$>[1..27]  -- map over the list [1..27] the function that
           drop          -- drops that many elements from
    ($cycle['a'..'z'])   -- the infinite cycled alphabet and
   take 26               -- keeps the next 26 chars and
  g                      -- appends the reverse of itself

                         -- now we have the first 27 lines

 g                       -- do another g to append the lower half
unlines                  -- join with newlines
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Øaṙ1ṭṙJ$ŒBŒḄY
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5hh4bmZMeG5reG5mUokxZJCxZLhuIRZ&input=)

### Explanation

```
Øaṙ1ṭṙJ$ŒBŒḄY  Main link. No arguments
Øa             Get the lowercase alphabet
  ṙ1           Rotate left by 1
    ṭ          Append to
       $       Monadic chain
      J          Indices of the alphabet [1, 2, ..., 26]
     ṙ           Rotate the alphabet by each
        ŒB     Bounce each rotation
          ŒḄ   Bounce the rotations
            Y  Join with newlines and print implicitly
```

Comment: `Øaṙ'JŒBŒḄY` for 10 :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks but that's missing the middle part which is why I had to do that `ṙ1ṭ` bit. Also `ØaṙJŒBŒḄY` is fine, you don't need the quick since it vectorizes on the right to 0

Comment: Totally missed that the diamond was not perfect! Oh well...

Answer (score 5):

## C, 76 bytes

Function, to be called as below. Prints capital letters.

```
f(i){for(i=2756;--i;)putchar(i%52?90-(abs(i%52-26)+abs(i/52-26)+25)%26:10);}

//call like this
main(){f();}
```

Simple approach, add the x and y distances from the centre of the square, plus an offset of 25 for the `a` in the middle, take modulo 26 and subract from `90`, the ASCII code for `Z`. Where `i%52`==0 a newline ASCII `10` is printed.

Comment: Your offset of `+25` is the same as `-1` in modulo 26

Comment: @KarlNapf C doesn't implement modulo of negative numbers the way mathematicians do. `-1%26` in C is -1, not 25. The result is a `[` in the centre instead of the expected `A`. Thanks anyway, you would have been correct in a language such as Ruby where `-1%26` does equal 25.

Answer (score 5):

## R, 71 bytes

```
cat(letters[outer(c(1:27,26:1),c(0:25,24:0),"+")%%26+1],sep="",fill=53)
```

`outer` creates a matrix with the indices of the letters, `letters[...]` then creates a vector with the correct letters in. `cat(...,sep="",fill=53)` then prints it out with the desired formatting.

Comment: Nice one! Somehow I had forgotten about the `fill` option for `cat`. Great way of printing formatted matrices.

Answer (score 5):

## Jelly, 11 bytes

```
27RØaṙŒḄŒBY
```

Explanation:

```
27R          range of 1...27
   Øa        the alphabet
     ṙ       rotate
      ŒḄŒB   bounce in both dimensions
          Y  join on newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>97</s> 96 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @user81655*

```
R=(n,s=25,c=(n%26+10).toString(36))=>s?c+R(n+1,s-1)+c:c
C=(n=1,r=R(n))=>n<27?r+`
${C(n+1)}
`+r:r
```

Two recursive functions; `C` is the one that outputs the correct text. Try it here:

```js
R=(n,s=25,c=(n%26+10).toString(36))=>s?c+R(n+1,s-1)+c:c
C=(n=1,r=R(n))=>n<27?r+`
${C(n+1)}
`+r:r

console.log(C())
```

Comment: @user81655 I always forget about string interpolation when newlines are involved :P

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>96</s> 85 bytes

Printing the uppercase version (saves 1 byte).

```python
R=range
for i in R(53):print''.join(chr(90-(abs(j-25)+abs(i-26)-1)%26)for j in R(51))
```

previous solution with help from muddyfish

```python
s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"*3
for i in range(53):j=min(i,52-i);print s[j+1:j+27]+s[j+25:j:-1]
```

Comment: isn't just typing the alphabet fewer chars?

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 255 bytes

```
@echo off
set l=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
set r=yxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
for /l %%i in (1,1,27)do call:u
for /l %%i in (1,1,25)do call:l
:l
set r=%r:~2%%l:~-1%.
set l=%l:~-2%%l:~0,-2%
:u
set r=%l:~-1%%r:~0,-1%
set l=%l:~1%%l:~0,1%
echo %l%%r%
```

Explanation: The subroutine `u` rotates the alphabet outwards by one letter from the centre, which is the pattern used in the top half of the desired output. The subroutine `l` rotates the alphabet inwards by two letters. It then falls through into the `u` subroutine, achieving an effective single letter inward rotation. Finally the last line is printed by allowing the code to fall through into the `l` subroutine.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 77 bytes

Requires `-E` at no extra cost.

Pretty standard approach... I don't like the calls to reverse I think there's likely a more maths based approach to this, will see how I get on!

```pl
@a=((a..z)x3)[$_..$_+26],$a=pop@a,(say@a,$a,reverse@a)for 1..26,reverse 1..25
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -E '@a=((a..z)x3)[$_..$_+26],$a=pop@a,(say@a,$a,reverse@a)for 1..26,reverse 1..25'
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by removing the whitespace after `reverse` in `reverse 1..25`. The `for` needs it though.

Comment: @simbabque maybe it's a Perl version thing, but `reverse1..25` results in `0..25`. I'm running `5.18.2`...

Comment: You're right. Because the bareword `reverse1` is undefined. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 119 bytes

I tried to exploit the two symmetry axes of the diamond, but this ended up more verbose than [Karl Napf's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97445/20929).

```
A='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
D=''
for k in range(1,27):
 D+=A[k:]+A[:k]
 D+=D[-2:-27:-1]+'\n'
print(D+D[:51]+D[::-1])
```

Comment: A good solution nonetheless! You can cut down 3 bytes by writing the for loop in 1 line: `for k in range(1,27):D+=A[k:]+A[:k];D+=D[-2:-27:-1]+'\n'`

Comment: shortened again: replace A with `'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza'` and replace `range(1,27)` with `range(26)`. [My byte count is now 114](https://repl.it/EJqg/0)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
unlines[[toEnum$mod(-abs j-abs i)26+97|j<-[-25..25]]|i<-[-26..26]]
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, 252 bytes

```
#define j q[y]
#define k(w,v) (v<'z')?(w=v+1):(w=97)
char q[28][52],d;main(){int y,x=1;y=1;j[0]=98;j[50]=98;for(;y<27;y++){for(;x<26;x++){(x<1)?(k(d,q[y-1][50])):(k(d,j[x-1]));j[50-x]=d;j[x]=d;}x=0;j[51]=0;puts(j);}strcpy(j,q[1]);for(;y;y--)puts(j);}
```

Formatted, macro-expanded version, which is hopefully more intelligible:

```
#define j q[y]
#define k(w,v) (v<'z')?(w=v+1):(w=97)
char q[28][52],d;
main(){
int y,x=1;
y=1;
q[1][0]=98;q[1][50]=98;
//98 takes one less byte to type than the equivalent 'b'
for(;y<27;y++){
    for(;x<26;x++){
        (x<1)?
            (k(d,q[y-1][50]))
            :(k(d,q[y][x-1]));
        q[y][50-x]=d;
        q[y][x]=d;
        }
    x=0;
    q[y][51]=0;
    puts(q[y]);
    }
strcpy(q[y],q[1]);
for(;y;y--)puts(q[y]);
}
```

I know this can't win, but I had fun trying. This is my first ever attempt at code golf.

Comment: Welcome to code golf, it's addicting haha ;).

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
GV'th+jj_t+j)K]0n'JOX
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=GV%27th%2Bjj_t%2Bj%29K%5D0n%27JOX&warnings=0)

```
GV          )         - repeat 26 times, initially push alphabet.
  'th+                -  push tos[1:]+tos[0]
      j               -  j = tos
       j              -  push j
        _t+           -  push pop+reversed(pop)[1:]
           j          -  push j
             K        - pop
              ]0      - list(stack)
                n'JOX - print "\n".join(^),
                      - splat ^[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, <sub><s>109</s> <s>105</s></sub> 78 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs the alphabet diamond to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For i=-26To 26:For j=-25To 25:?Chr(65+(52-(Abs(j)+Abs(i)))Mod 26);:Next:?:Next
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to ASCII-only.*

```
Ｆ²⁷«Ｐ✂×β³⊕ι⁺ι²⁷↓»‖Ｂ↓→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxDsIwDAD3vMKjTdOlDEgdEStLeUEbJdSS1aDgtkKIt5tIveGWuzCPJeRRzFIugN2F4Ougcl9F@VV4UXwIh4gnnDycyUPTcBVW1ZvouPMWsb/lfSH3c26ISWLQ66oaS5LPkTz0Az9nJTNrN2vf8gc) Link is to verbose version.

...I need to work on my Charcoal-fu. :P

Comment: [some easy bytes off](https://tio.run/##JYsxDsIwDAD3vMKjDekCA1JHxMLAUl5QgkMtmaQKbhFCvD1U6m2n04WhLyH3WmvMBXB3IPg6WLhMajIWSYZXlcC4wZuHPXk4p1D4ycn4jrL4FsXDMhKtY54Z21N@J3I/5zqOysGOkxmXqJ81eWg7eQxGtdZmrs1L/w)

Comment: *Now* I find out that the fourth argument to `Slice` is optional. >_>

Comment: All (yes, all four) arguments are optional

Comment: wat, what does niladic `Slice` even do?

Comment: Same as in Python, deep copy

Comment: Deep copy of what? With no arguments...

Comment: Oh wait nvm yeah the first argument is required :P

Comment: [oh more bytes off](https://tio.run/##DcexDoJADADQ3a/o2GpZcCBhNC4OLvAFZy1yST3IWSV@ffVtT@ZUZUkWcU0rth3DaFkU93hjOBLDpUjVpxbXO@b/D5gZ2o6IdoNOpuKnt7vWyb7Yn5etMPRDfsxOEdF8onnZDw) [wait even more](https://tio.run/##BcExDsIwDADAnVdktIW7dKnUkbIwsJQXBNclkUxSBQPq6907TrFxjep@jxv0A4WHZhaYdlaZUt3gSeEMmUI/IFK4FW7ylmKyQEbE0yyrCtvlayZt1R3Ga/0XCuOcX8nQ3bufdx89AA)

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>191</s> <s>179</s> <s>166</s> <s>165</s> 139 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen 
-14 bytes thanks to Zacharý
-26 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```cpp
#import<cstdio>
#define C j;)putchar(97+j
main(){for(int i=0,j,d=1;i<53;d+=i++/26?-1:1){for(j=d;26+d>C++%26);for(j--;d<=--C%26);puts("");}}
```

Comment: You can save 12 bytes like this: `#include<iostream>
int main(){for(int i=0,j,d=1;i<53;d+=i++/26?-1:1){for(j=0;j<26;)std::cout<<char((j+++d)%26+97);for(j=24;j>=0;)std::cout<<char((j--+d)%26+97);std::cout<<'\n';};}`

Comment: Dang it Kevin, ya ninja'd me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks you for the help. By the way, your code in the comment contained unprintable unicode characters.

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun That's something that happens automatically in the comments I'm afraid. It's indeed pretty annoying when you try to copy-paste code from it.. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yup, i get "0 is an unknown identifier" and "std doesn't have cout identifier/type" and so on...

Comment: You can abuse macros by adding this: `#define C j;)std::cout<<char(97+(d+j`, and then changing the last line to this:
`int main(){for(int i=0,j,d=1;i<53;d+=i++/26?-1:1){for(j=0;26>C++)%26);for(j=24;0<=C--)%26);std::cout<<'\n';};}`

Comment: Wait ... what is that stray semicolon doing after the for loop?

Comment: Suggest `1-++i/27*2` instead of `i++/26?-1:1`

Answer (score 2):

**VBA (Excel) , 116 Bytes**

```
Sub a()
For i=-26To 26
For j=-25To 25
b=b & Chr(65+(52-(Abs(j)+Abs(i))) Mod 26)
Next
Debug.Print b
b=""
Next
End Sub
```

Following Sir Joffan's Logic. :D

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 64 bytes

```powershell
1..27+26..1|%{$y=$_
-join(0..25+24..0|%{[char](97+($_+$y)%26)})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz8hc28hMT8@wRrVapdJWJZ5LNys/M0/DAChjqm1koqdnAJSJTs5ILIrVsDTX1lCJ11ap1FQ1MtOs1az9/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>128</s> <s>115</s> 114 bytes

```
a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for(o=[i=27];i--;)o[26-i]=o[26+i]=(a=(p=a.slice(1))+a[0])+[...p].reverse().join``
o
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy - <strike>103</strike> 97 bytes

I realise there are cleverer ways of doing this but...

```
{t=('a'..'z').join();q={it[-2..0]};c=[];27.times{t=t[1..-1]+t[0];c<<t+q(t)};(c+q(c)).join('\n')}
```

When run the result of the script is the requested answer.

(Thanks to [carusocomputing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/carusocomputing) for the tip on saving 7 bytes).

Updated example accordingly on:

See http://ideone.com/MkQeoW

Comment: Instead of the for loop you can use `27.times(){}` and save 7 bytes ;).

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 293 bytes

```
(let*((ls list->string)(rr reverse)(sr(λ(s)(ls(rr(string->list s))))))(let p((s(ls(for/list((i(range 97 123)))(integer->char i))))
(n 0)(ol'()))(let*((c(string-ref s 0))(ss(substring s 1 26))(s(string-append ss(string c)(sr ss))))(if(< n 53)(p s(+ 1 n)(cons s ol))
(append(rr ol)(cdr ol))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (define (sr s)           ; sub-fn reverse string;
    (list->string
     (reverse
      (string->list s))))
  (let loop ((s
              (list->string
               (for/list
                   ((i
                     (range 97 123)))
                 (integer->char i))))
             (n 0)
             (ol '()))
    (define c (string-ref s 0))
    (define ss (substring s 1 26))
    (set! s (string-append
             ss 
             (string c)
             (sr ss)))
    (if (< n 53)
        (loop s (add1 n) (cons s ol))
        (append (reverse ol) (rest ol)))))
```

Testing:

```
(f)
```

Output:

```
'("bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb"
  "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedc"
  "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed"
  "efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfe"
  "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgf"
  "ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg"
  "hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjih"
  "ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkji"
  "jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkj"
  "klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlk"
  "lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponml"
  "mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponm"
  "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpon"
  "opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpo"
  "pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqp"
  "qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrq"
  "rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsr"
  "stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvuts"
  "tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvut"
  "uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvu"
  "vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwv"
  "wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxw"
  "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyx"
  "yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazy"
  "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaz"
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
  "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb"
  "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedc"
  "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed"
  "efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfe"
  "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgf"
  "ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg"
  "hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjih"
  "ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkji"
  "jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkj"
  "klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlk"
  "lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponml"
  "mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponm"
  "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpon"
  "opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpo"
  "pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqp"
  "qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrq"
  "rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsr"
  "stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvuts"
  "tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvut"
  "uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvu"
  "vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwv"
  "wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxw"
  "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyx"
  "yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazy"
  "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaz"
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
  "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb"
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
  "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaz"
  "yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazy"
  "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyx"
  "wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxw"
  "vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwv"
  "uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvu"
  "tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvut"
  "stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvuts"
  "rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsr"
  "qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrq"
  "pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqp"
  "opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpo"
  "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpon"
  "mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponm"
  "lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponml"
  "klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlk"
  "jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkj"
  "ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkji"
  "hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjih"
  "ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg"
  "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgf"
  "efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfe"
  "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed"
  "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedc"
  "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb"
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"
  "zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaz"
  "yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazy"
  "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyx"
  "wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxw"
  "vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwv"
  "uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvu"
  "tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvut"
  "stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvuts"
  "rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsr"
  "qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrq"
  "pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqp"
  "opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpo"
  "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqpon"
  "mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponm"
  "lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponml"
  "klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlk"
  "jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkj"
  "ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkji"
  "hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjih"
  "ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihg"
  "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgf"
  "efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfe"
  "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed"
  "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedc"
  "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <del>21</del> 19 bytes

```
j+PKm+PJ.<Gd_JS27_K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0s7wDtXO8BLz8Y9Jd4r2Mg83vv/fwA)

**Explanation:**

```
j+PKm+PJ.<Gd_JS27_K   expects no input

j                     joins on new line
 +   +                joins two strings
  P   P               prints everything but the last element
   K                  initialize K and implicitly print
    m                 for...in loop, uses d as iterator variable
       J              initialize J and implicitly print
        .<            cyclically rotate
          G           initialized to the lowercase alphabet
           d          iterating variables of m
            _    _    reverse
             J        call J
              S27     indexed range of 27
                  K   call K
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
zl{«:}«¹╬,
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=emwlN0IlQUIlM0ElN0QlQUIlQjkldTI1NkMlMkM_)

Explanation:

```
z           push the lowercase alphabet
 l{  }      repeat length times
   «          put the 1st letter at the end
    :         duplicate
      «     put the 1st letter at the end (as the last thing called is duplicate)
       ¹    wrap the stack in an array
        ╬,  quad-palindromize with 1 X and Y overlap
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>154</s> <s>153</s> <s>151</s> <s>148</s> <s>147</s> <s>142</s> 141 bytes

```java
v->{var r="";for(int i=0,j,d=1;i<53;d+=1-++i/27*2){for(j=d;j<26+d;)r+=(char)(j++%26+97);for(j--;j>d;)r+=(char)(--j%26+97);r+="\n";}return r;}
```

Port of [*@HatsuPointerKun* C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141520/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well.
-8 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.
-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##VY9BS8QwEIXv/oqhICRmU92KLjKb/QfuRfCiHmLS1cRuukzTgJT@9pq69SDMHObN4/E@r5OW3n5NptFdB4/aheECwIVY00GbGvbzCfAUyYUPMOy5dRYSx6yOefN0UUdnYA8BFExJ7oakCUgVBR5aYjkKnLpZ@ZVVa3Tbu1u0Qq2lEO662lxVfJhdXln02@peWOQkFDOfmjjzQlxm7WHDf6O8lOh3/xxS@j9HFovXUOBIdewpAOE44bniqX9vcsWlaZoRjpmUnale3kDzBfO7i/WxbPtYnvIrslAaFvqm4QvxOP0A)

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##VY/BTsMwEETvfMUqEpIt46gJahG4Dl9AL0hcgIOx09YmdaqNYwlF@fbg0ByotHPYndFqnlNRcWe@J92oroMXZf1wA2B9qHGvdA27eQV4DWj9ATR5a62BSEW6jklpuqCC1bADDxKmyKshKgSUWSb2LZL0Cqxc3bkkIwtht@t7YZi0jFXl@pkXTwUd5qBw23IjKDJJ9FEhJcQxxgy9LTfs8YH@PXOcC1etrlKcu3@pZGQfPhMj1qFHDyjGSVyKnvuvJhVd@sYZ5JR4yYXt/RMUXWB/ulCf8rYP@TlZgfhcE983DV24x@kX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 106 bytes

```
{(0..52).map{i->(0..50).map{j->print((90-((Math.abs(j-25)+Math.abs(i-26)-1)+26)%26).toChar())}
println()}}
```

### Beautified

```
{
    (0..52).map {i->
        (0..50).map {j->
            print((90 - ((Math.abs(j - 25) + Math.abs(i - 26) - 1)+26) % 26).toChar())
        }
        println()
    }
}
```

### Test

```
var v:()->Unit =
{(0..52).map{i->(0..50).map{j->print((90-((Math.abs(j-25)+Math.abs(i-26)-1)+26)%26).toChar())}
println()}}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    v()
}
```

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##PYvBCsIwEETv@YpchF3KhlqoYKkB8exJ/ID1YJvapiWNBSn59hgqOPAYHsy8Rt8bGxd2cqkASd@t8fIUV8iVKgtUA0@rIb1p/tOO9OSM9QDHnACu7FvFjxk6KkrM/mqoOCDtMUu1Syg/Xlp2gBjE9u8tYAjx@bZyYGOBXTNX8uwcf@qbT4tGo1yFTFkARRDxCw)

Port of [@Karl Napf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53667/karl-napf)'s answer

Answer (score 1):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 86 bytes

```
0ForI=-26To26:ForJ=-25To25:?Left$(Chr$(65+(52-(Abs(J)+Abs(I)))Mod26),1);:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNNW18gsJN/IzArI8QJyTIEcUyt7n9S0EhUN54wiFQ0zU20NUyNdDcekYg0vTW0Q5ampqembn2JkpqljqGlt5ZdaUeJlZQ@mPf//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 89 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
For i=-26 To 26
For j=-25 To 25
Print Chr(65+(52-(Abs(j)+Abs(i)))Mod 26)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0gh01bXyEwhJF/ByIwLxM8C8k3BfFOugKLMvBIF54wiDTNTbQ1TI10Nx6RijSxNbRCVqamp6ZufAtSnyeWXWlECUW0NZv//DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 160 bytes

Declared `Sub`routine that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Dim S,I,J
For I=-26To 26
S=""
For J=-25To 25
S+=Chr(65+(52-(Math.Abs(j)+Math.Abs(i)))Mod 26)
Next
Console.WriteLine(S)
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49C4MwGIT3/IrglKBxEOLmUPoBStMlhc6xBnyL5gUTS/99mtrS6Y7n4O6e4Fczid54uAtng5jRYYwKh3WyVBG99lQZcOQAM9VFW3TkhAttG1HVV6RVTXSTZRvrEpMfJonOm/24sFrmTFaCKRPGctd79uD53wPnPM2kCk4u9hXIHp3HyZa3BYI9g7NM/5KjG2g6sun3WYxv)

Comment: Are you attempting to tell me that this challenge is "Basic" or something?

Comment: *BA DUM TSSSSSSSSSSS*

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Lol!, Nope - I just realized that there were a couple of flavors of BASIC on TIO and thought I would give them a try - and as it turns out there are some pretty huge bugs in uBASIC (it cannot take any input on TIO at the moment) so alphabet challenges are the best I can do for all of the BASIC flavors

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 74 bytes

Now I'm telling you that this challenge *BASIC*. /sarcasm

```
For i=-26To 26
For j=-25To 25
?Chr$(65+Mod(Abs(j)+Abs(i),26));
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SCHTVtfILCRfwciMC8TNAnJNQVxTLnvnjCIVDTNTbd/8FA3HpGKNLE1tEJWpqWNkpqlpzeWXWlHCZQ@m/v8HAA)

Comment: "YA BASIC!" - Had me laughing, thanks for that one lol.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
Aā._Ć€ûû»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8UijXvyRtkdNaw7vPrz70O7//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) v6+, 59 bytes

```powershell
1..27+26..1|%{-join(('a'..'z'*3)[$_..($_+25)+($_+24)..$_])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz8hc28hMT8@wRrVaNys/M09DQz1RXU9PvUpdy1gzWiVeT09DJV7byFRTG0ybaOrpqcTHatb@/w8A)

Ranges on ranges on ranges.

Comment: maybe an `gu` could try?

Comment: @mazzy I have no idea how I'd work `gu` into this one. If you have it, you should post it as your own.

Comment: You're right. `gu` useless. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz8hc28hMT8@wRrVaNys/M09DQz1RXU9PvUpdy1gzWiVeT09DpcpWJV7byFRTW6VKT08lPrYmvVSz9v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [FALSE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FALSE), 137 bytes

```
1c:53 0$d:[65@$0=~\1-\][@@\c;+d;1=[1_c:]?$26=[%0 1d:]?$1_=[%25]?$@+1b:51[$0=~][$26=[1_b:]?\$,b;+[$a:$64=[90a:]?91=[65a:]?a;]!\1-]#%%10,]#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BDsIgEER/pabLiZqwVUgKIfIfy4YA1ZM37/46Lt5mJm9mXvX9eY6B3dvbYuD05GwCE78Zr5kppdyDPgNGwtI9P2B3kZRZ8JwGi5jdikoam7dIs8r0p7A0YTJsLWiC6sHdIx2mSnjInrNT1cAXueJVKTQbr2P8AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `jr`, 11 bytes

```
27ƛkaǓøm;øm
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=27%C6%9Bka%C7%93%C3%B8m%3B%C3%B8m&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
27ƛ     ;    # For each number x in range [1..27]:
   ka        #   Lowercase alphabet
     Ǔ       #   Rotate it left x times
      øm     #   Mirror without duplicating middle
         øm  # Mirror without duplicating middle
             # 'j' flag - Join top of stack with newlines and print
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 48 bytes

```
(}:@|.,])(],.}.@|."1)(1+i._26)|."0 1 a.{~97+i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/oPBBq1Vg41ejqxmhqxOnq1ekC2kqGmhqF2pl68kZkmkGegYKiQqFddZ2kOFDMyAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 221 bytes

```
(let((k 26)a(s"~26{~a~}~25{~a~}~%"))(#4=dotimes(i k)(push(code-char(- 90 i))a))(let*((u(append a a a))(b(reverse u)))(#4#(i 27)(#3=format t s #1=(nthcdr(1+ i)u)#2=(nthcdr(- k i)b)))(rotatef u b)(#4#(i k)(#3#t s #2##1#))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PczbCsIwDAbgVwkrQqIMXNWJF3uYrutY2aGlB2/EvXrtJkouEn7@fHLS3qaEkwqII/CaBPpi5fVrFet75bfvPhREyK5NZ4KelUcNI6GNfkBpOlXKQTgs4XEGTSRyNXNHxIjCWrV0ILbJcYtOPZXzCiLtIMsSv@fr0vTGzSJAAA@sanAJg@wcVqdMRmL8n5Qw5qjd/p0JIqgeIrQ/bNwstiOcsYrlGqX0AQ)

More readable version:

```
(let (a)                             ; variable to hold the alphabet
  (dotimes (i 26)                    ; creation of the alphabet as list
    (push (code-char (- 90 i)) a))
  (let* ((u (append a a a))          ; make three copies of a
         (b (reverse u)))                ; reverse u
    (dotimes (i 27)                  ; first half: form a line with two parts
       (format t "~26{~a~}~25{~a~}~%" (nthcdr (1+ i) u) (nthcdr (- 26 i) b)))
    (rotatef u b)                    ; exchange the role of u and b
    (dotimes (i 26)                  ; second half: exchange the two parts
       (format t "~26{~a~}~25{~a~}~%" (nthcdr (- 26 i) b) (nthcdr (1+ i) u)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>15</s> 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;26ÆCé´T êÃê
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=OzI2xkPptFQg6sPq)

```
;26ÆCé´T êÃê
 26Æ             :Map the range [0,26)
;   C            :  Lowercase alphabet
     é           :  Rotate right by
      ´T         :    T (initially 0) prefix decremented
         ê       :  Palindromise
          Ã      :End map
           ê     :Palindromise
                 :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 31 bytes

```
{⍵⍪1 0↓⊖⍵}{⍵,0 1↓⌽⍵}↑(⌽∘⎕A)¨⍳27
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE6of9W591LvKUMHgUdvkR13TgNxakJiOgYIhSKRnL0jkUdtEDRCzYwZQl6PmoRWPejcbmf//DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 51 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1 .Q.a t{rotate[y;x]x,1_(|)x}/:(1+t),1,(-)t:(!)26;
```

**Explanation:**

Build the range of `1..26,1,0,-1..-25`, feed this into a lambda that rotates the range 0..25 and indexes in at the range `0..25,24..0`... Then use this to index into the lowercase alphabet.

```
-1 .Q.a t{rotate[y;x]x,1_reverse x}/:(1+t),1,neg t:til 26; / ungolfed
-1                                                       ; / print to stdout and swallow return value
                                                 t:til 26  / store range of 0..25 in variable t
                                             neg           / negate (0..-25)
                                           1,              / prepend 1
                                     (1+t),                / prepend 1+t (1..26)
        t{                        }/:                      / lambda function with parameters t, and each-right
                         reverse x                         / x = t = 0..25, reversed is 25..0
                       1_                                  / 1 drop, so 24..0
                     x,                                    / prepend x, so 0..25,24..0
          rotate[y;x]                                      / rotate x by y (rotate[1;"abc"] -> "bca")
   .Q.a                                                    / index into alphabet at these indices
```

**Notes:**

Feels like it should be able to be golfed further, building the ranges seems clunky.

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), <s>44 25 21</s> 19 bytes

```
{p+)'a'"Pp+J''_Q)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/ukBbUz1RXSmgQNtLXT0@ULO29v9/AA)

## Explanation:

```
{p+)'a'"Pp+J''_Q)}}
{                     - For each
 p+)'a'               - 'abc..xyzazyx..abc'
       "              - Iteration command begin
        P             - Print
         p            - palindromize 'cde..xyzabazyx..cde'
          +           - concatenate 'cde..xyzab'
           J''        - join with nothing 'cde..xyza'
              _       - reverse ['cde...xyz', 'a']
               Q)}    - split ) at } ['a','cdef..xyz']
                  }   - current element (say 'b' for 2nd iteration)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 166 bytes

```
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb____________________________________________________
+(`([a-z]+)_(_+)
$1¶$1$2¶$1
(.)(.{24})(.)(.{24})._
$2$3$1$3$4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKyk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisiqxqrKivKy0pLiosCA/LzcnOyszIz0tNSU5KZ4MwKWtkaARnahbFautGa8Rr63JpWJ4aJuKoYoRiOTS0NPU0Ks2MqnVRLD04rlUjFSMgWqMVUz@/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
(⍉⊢⍪1↓⊖)⍣2⍉1↓27 27⍴⎕a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb////XeNTb@ahr0aPeVYaP2iY/6pqm@ah3sRFQEMQ1MlcwMn/UuwWoIREA)

With the alphabet (`⎕a`) fill in row-major order a 27x27 matrix (`27 27⍴`), then drop the first row (`1↓`) and transpose (`⍉`).

Do this twice (`⍣2`): concatenate to the bottom (`⍪`) of this matrix (`⊢`) a vertically reversed copy (`⊖`) without its first row (`1↓`) and transpose (`⍉`) the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
éÑ8╟╘"╧ö↑D☼▓}
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82a538c7d422cf9418440fb27d&i=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 111 bytes

```elixir
import Enum
c=?a..?z
a=map 1..26,&(drop(c,&1)++slice c,0,&1)
map a++[hd a]++reverse(a),&IO.puts&1++tl reverse&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/M7cgv6hEwTWvNJcr2dY@UU/Pvoor0TY3sUDBUE/PyExHTSOlKL9AI1lHzVBTW7s4JzM5VSFZxwDE5QKpStTWjs5IUUiM1dYuSi1LLSpO1UjU1FHz9NcrKC0pVjPU1i7JUYDKqBn@/w8A)

Feel like there are some key savings I'm missing here...