# Confusing Alphabet Staircase

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Given no input, output this interesting alphabet pattern in either case (the case has to be consistent) via an [accepted output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods):

```
A
AB
ACBC
ADBDCD
AEBECEDE
AFBFCFDFEF
AGBGCGDGEGFG
AHBHCHDHEHFHGH
AIBICIDIEIFIGIHI
AJBJCJDJEJFJGJHJIJ
AKBKCKDKEKFKGKHKIKJK
ALBLCLDLELFLGLHLILJLKL
AMBMCMDMEMFMGMHMIMJMKMLM
ANBNCNDNENFNGNHNINJNKNLNMN
AOBOCODOEOFOGOHOIOJOKOLOMONO
APBPCPDPEPFPGPHPIPJPKPLPMPNPOP
AQBQCQDQEQFQGQHQIQJQKQLQMQNQOQPQ
ARBRCRDRERFRGRHRIRJRKRLRMRNRORPRQR
ASBSCSDSESFSGSHSISJSKSLSMSNSOSPSQSRS
ATBTCTDTETFTGTHTITJTKTLTMTNTOTPTQTRTST
AUBUCUDUEUFUGUHUIUJUKULUMUNUOUPUQURUSUTU
AVBVCVDVEVFVGVHVIVJVKVLVMVNVOVPVQVRVSVTVUV
AWBWCWDWEWFWGWHWIWJWKWLWMWNWOWPWQWRWSWTWUWVW
AXBXCXDXEXFXGXHXIXJXKXLXMXNXOXPXQXRXSXTXUXVXWX
AYBYCYDYEYFYGYHYIYJYKYLYMYNYOYPYQYRYSYTYUYVYWYXY
AZBZCZDZEZFZGZHZIZJZKZLZMZNZOZPZQZRZSZTZUZVZWZXZYZ
```

Trailing spaces and newlines are acceptable, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed, and this happens to be [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87496/alphabet-triangle), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/90497/alphabet-triangle-strikes-again)

Comment: BTW if I see an amazing answer I will bounty it 50 rep

Comment: The leading `A` really messes things up for me...

Comment: Why the downvote? Can I improve anything?

Comment: Some people simply don't like these kind of challenges I think.

Comment: @ETHproductions It simplifies things for me!

Comment: Can it be lowercase?

Comment: @l4m2 Sure thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ［Ｋ＊¹＋］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNCJXVGRjJCJXVGRjBBJUI5JXVGRjBCJXVGRjNE,v=0,run)

Explanation:

```
Ｚ［     ］ for each prefix of the uppercase alphabet
    Ｋ        pop off the last letter
     ＊       and join the rest of the string with that character
      ¹＋     and append the current iterated character to it
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your previous answer?

Comment: @Neil good question. Not sure

Comment: Accepted! You beat Jelly and Charcoal by two bytes!

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ØAjṪ$Ƥż¹Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9qZWxsef//w5hBauG5qiTGpMW8wrlZ//8)

#### How it works

```
ØAjṪ$Ƥż¹Y  Main link. No arguments.

ØA         Yield "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".
     Ƥ     Map the link to the left over all prefixes, i.e., ["A", "AB", ...].
    $        Combine the two links to the left into a chain.
   Ṫ           Tail; yield and remove the last letter of each prefix.
  j            Join the remainder, using that letter as separator.
      ż¹   Zip the resulting strings and the letters of the alphabet.
        Y  Separate the results by linefeeds.
```

Comment: Oh, haha and I was just about to post `ØAjṪ$ƤżØAY` :D

Answer (score 7):

## C, 82 bytes

```c
f(i,j){for(i=!puts("A");++i<26;puts(""))for(j=0;j++<i*2;)putchar(65+(j&1?j/2:i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1MnS7M6Lb9II9NWsaC0pFhDyVFJ01pbO9PGyMwaIqCkqQlSkGVrYJ2lrW2TqWVkrQmUSc5ILNIwM9XWyFIztM/SN7LK1NS0rv2fmVeikJuYmaehyVXNpQAEaRqa1ly1/wE)

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｅα⁺⪫…ακιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUAjUUchIKe0WMMrPzNPw7kyOSfVOSMfLJytqaOQCcaamtb////XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 α          Predefined uppercase alphabet
Ｅ           Map over each character
    …ακ     Get current prefix of alphabet
   ⪫   ι    Join with current character
  ⁺     ι   Append current character
            Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 50 bytes

```r
l=LETTERS
for(i in 0:25)cat(l[0:i],"
",sep=l[i+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8fWxzUkxDUomCstv0gjUyEzT8HAyshUMzmxRCMn2sAqM1ZHiUtJpzi1wDYnOlPbMFbz/38A)

Perhaps the cleverest part here is using `letters[0]` for the empty string to get `cat(character(0),'\n',sep="A")` to print the first line.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
n=65;s='';exec'c=chr(n);print c.join(s)+c;s+=c;n+=1;'*26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCsAgDADAr3SLNlBQqEvIa4KgHaIYh/b16d38dhua3ZXLTcYAVN8qICxtBY00V9d9yPWMrsEiChmykCIngjMX9x8)

Answer (score 5):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) routine (C64), 39 bytes

```
A9 41 20 D2 FF AA A8 84 FB E4 FB B0 0B 8A 20 D2 FF 98 20 D2 FF E8 D0 F1 A9 0D
20 D2 FF A2 41 C0 5A F0 03 C8 D0 E1 60
```

Position-independet machine code subroutine, clobbers A, X and Y.

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22calst.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMCpQSDS/6qohPvk+7ALiiDS/5gg0v/o0PGpDSDS/6JBwFrwA8jQ4WA=%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22calst.prg%22%7D%7D)

The demo loads at `$C000`, so use `SYS49152` to call the routine.

---

#### Commented disassembly:

```
A9 41       LDA #$41            ; 'A'
20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2           ; Kernal CHROUT (output character)
AA          TAX                 ; copy to X (current pos)
A8          TAY                 ; copy to Y (current endpos)
  .outerloop:
84 FB       STY $FB             ; endpos to temporary
  .innerloop:
E4 FB       CPX $FB             ; compare pos with endpos
B0 0B       BCS .eol            ; reached -> do end of line
8A          TXA                 ; current pos to accu
20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2           ; and output
98          TYA                 ; endpos to accu
20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2           ; and output
E8          INX                 ; next character
D0 F1       BNE .innerloop      ; (repeat)
  .eol:
A9 0D       LDA #$0D            ; load newline
20 D2 FF    JSR $FFD2           ; and output
A2 41       LDX #$41            ; re-init current pos to 'A'
C0 5A       CPY #$5A            ; test endpos to 'Z'
F0 03       BEQ .done           ; done when 'Z' reached
C8          INY                 ; next endpos
D0 E1       BNE .outerloop      ; (repeat)
  .done:
60          RTS
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <strike>0.1.0</strike> 0.10.0, 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/i-want-8-bits-for-every-character/265917#265917)

```
∵(&p+@A♭≡⊂⇡.)⇡26&pf@A
```

[See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4oi1KCZwK0BB4pmt4omh4oqC4oehLinih6EyNiZwZkBBCg==)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 4):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>169</s> <s>143</s> <s>124</s> 123 bytes

```
	L =LEN(1)
	OUTPUT ='A'
I	&UCASE (ARB K L) . R L . S :F(END)
	O =K =
T	R K L . K :F(O)
	O =O K S :(T)
O 	OUTPUT =O :(I)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NHwdbH1U/DUJOL0z80JCA0RMFW3VGdy5NTLdTZMdhVQcMxyEnBW8FHU0FPIUjBB0gGK1i5abj6uYB0KNh6K9hyhXAGgZQA5bxBcv4QGX8gD6hWI0STy18Bbrg/UMRTkwuo//9/AA)

Explanation for older version of the code:

```
i &ucase len(x) . r len(1) . s	;* set r to the first x characters and s to the x+1th.
 o =				;* set o,i to empty string
 i =
t r len(i) len(1) . k :f(o)	;* set k to the ith letter of r. on failure (no match), go to o.
 o =o s k			;* concatenate o,s,k
 i =i + 1 :(t)			;* increment i, goto t
o o s =				;* remove the first occurrence of s (the first character for x>1, and nothing otherwise)
 output =o s			;* output o concatenated with s
 x =lt(x,25) x + 1 :s(i)	;* increment x, goto i if x<25.
end
```

The problem here is the first line

using `o s k` will add an extra `s`eparator character at the beginning of each line and also not have an `s` at the end. This is OK because line `t` will jump over the following two lines when `x=0`. This means that `o` will still be blank. Hence, `o s =` will remove the first `s` character from `o`, and then we can simply print `o s` to have the appropriate last `s`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>93</s> <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```java
v->{String t="";for(char c=64;++c<91;t+=c)System.out.println(t.join(c+"",t.split(""))+c);}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* by printing directly instead of returning

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwDIbvPkXoqaVaEESQOt9AL4IX8VDj1M6ajjUbiOzZZ3VCfkLCD99Xuc7NYl1SdXkMGFxKsHWe3hMAT1w2V4cl7L4nQBf9BVAevqtTNv/6nDyJHXuEHRAUMHSzzXvPjacbcCGEvcZG4t01gMVyYbXG9WpuWReo9q/E5dPElk2d@xxIsqmiJ4laiCmbVAfPUgilNCrbD3bk1e05ZN4f@9N6Zmk5Uo8np0ZhMiipDeHv2g8f)

```java
v->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  String t="";           //  Temp-String, starting empty
  for(char c=64;++c<91;  //  Loop over the letters of the alphabet:
      t+=c)              //    After every iteration: append the letter to the temp-String
    System.out.println(  //   Print with trailing new-line:
       r.join(c+"",t.split(""))
                         //    The temp-String with the current letter as delimiter
       +c);}             //    + the current letter as trailing character
```

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwDIbvPkXoqaVaEESQOt9AL4IX8VDj1M6ajjUbiOzZZ3VCfkLCD99Xuc7NYl1SdXkMGFxKsHWe3hMAT1w2V4cl7L4nQBf9BVAevqtTNv/6nDyJHXuEHRAUMHSzzXvPjacbcCGEvcZG4t01gMVyYbXG9WpuWReo9q/E5dPElk2d@xxIsqmiJ4laiCmbVAfPUgilNCrbD3bk1e05ZN4f@9N6Zmk5Uo8np0ZhMiipDeHv2g8f) (just using stdout instead of returning).

Comment: Nice answer! I ported to C# to see if it was shorter and I get 91 (more if I include `System.`) :)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes

```js
f=
_=>[..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"].map((c,i,a)=>a.slice(0,i).join(c)+c).join`
`
;document.write('<pre>'+f());
```

Save 9 bytes if a string array return value is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>44</s> 34 bytes

```
"BA"oao"ZA"\=?;1+40.
o1+:{::o}=?\:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nJUSk/MV8pylEpxtbe2lDbxECPK99Q26rayiq/1tY@xur/fwA)

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 44 bytes

```
"A"o10ao\55*=?;1+40.
1+:{:}=?\:"A"+o{:}"A"+o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8lRKd/QIDE/xtRUy9be2lDbxECPy1Dbqtqq1tY@xgoorZ0PZIPp//8B)

As I use a different route to producing the output I've posted my own ><> answer; The other ><> answer can be found [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153190/62009)

Big thanks to Jo king for spotting I didn't need to keep putting "A" onto the stack if I just compared against "Z" instead of 26. (-10 bytes)

#### Explanation

The explanation will follow the flow of the code.

```
"BA"                 : Push "BA" onto the stack;
                       [] -> [66, 65]
    oao              : Print the stack top then print a new line;
                       [66, 65] -> [66]
       "ZA"\         : Push "ZA" onto the stack then move down to line 2;
                       [66, 90, 65]
o          \:        : Duplicate the stack top then print
 1+:                 : Add one to the stack top then duplicate;
                       [66, 90, 65, 65]
    {::              : Shift the stack right 1 place then duplicate the stack top twice;
                       [90, 65, 65, 66, 66]
       o}            : Print the stack top then shift the stack left 1 place;
                       [66, 90, 65, 65, 66]
         =?\         : Comparison for equality on the top 2 stack items then move to line 1 if equal otherwise continue on line 2;
                       [66, 90, 65]
           \=?;      : Comparison for equality on the top 2 stack items then quit if equal else continue on line 1;
                       [66]
               1+    : Add 1 to the stack top;
                       [67]
                 40. : Move the code pointer to column 4 row 0 of the code box and continue execution of code.
```

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nJUSm/jMvW3tpQ207JUSkxP0YpSokr31DbqtrKKr/W1j7G6v9/AA). Your method is much better than mine

Comment: inb4 "crossed out 44 is still 44 ;("

Comment: @JoKing Excellent spot with comparing to Z, only improvement I made was moving line logic and placing the Z in the middle of the stack items to save using those quote marks again.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 56 bytes

```powershell
"A";65..89|%{([char[]](65..$_)-join[char]++$_)+[char]$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8lRydrMVE/PwrJGtVojOjkjsSg6NlYDJKQSr6mblZ@ZBxaM1dYG8rUhbJX42v//AQ)

Loops `65` to `89`, each iteration constructing a `char` array of `65` to the current number `$_`, then `-join`s that array together into a string with the next character, then tacks on that character at the end.

Change the `89` to some other ASCII number to see the behavior better.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) (`-R` flag), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
;B¬
ËiU¯E qD
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0KsCqNzMFkgcVggK1g=&input=LVI=)

Comment: If only there were a shortcut for `s0,`! ;p

Comment: [12 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0KsCstpVa9FIHFE&input=LVI=). But why aren't you counting the `-R` here?

Comment: @Shaggy Oh wow, I knew I was missing something :P The `i` trick is great, thanks! As for the flag, there appears to be a [new consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/42545) that each unique invocation of a program should be considered a separate language. (which makes Japt's flag system seem kind of cheaty...)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```hs
'A':unlines[init['A'..x]>>=(:[x])|x<-['A'..'Z']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfXFKUmZeuYKsQ81/dUd2qNC8nMy@1ODozL7MkGiigp1cRa2dnq2EVXRGrWVNhowsRVI9Sj439n5uYmQfUWVBaElxSpAAx6f@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA)

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to totallyhuman!*

Answer (score 2):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 84 bytes

This is actually what inspired this challenge:

```
Write 65
Count i while i-26 {
Count b while b-i {
Write b+65
Write i+65
}
Write 10
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/z@8KLMkVcHMlMs5vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPXyEyhGiqYBBVM0s0EikF0JGkD9UCYmSBmLZRjaMBV@/8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>44</s> 34 bytes

```ruby
?A.upto(?Z){|w|puts [*?A...w]*w+w}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/395Rr7SgJF/DPkqzuqa8pqC0pFghWgsoqqdXHqtVrl1e@/8/AA)

Thanks benj2240 for getting it down to 37 bytes. And of course crossed out 44 blah blah.

Comment: Here's a [37-byte version](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkbD3lFPzz5KUy83saC6prwmWgskoFceq1WuXV6rpaL//z8A "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform)

Port from Kevin Cruijssen's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153240/15214):

### <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```cs
_=>{var t="";for(char c='@';++c<91;t+=c)Console.WriteLine(string.Join(c+"",t.Skip(0))+c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BSwMxEIXv@RVhL02IhnqUGFH2UCgtCHvwHMapDq6JzUwLZdnfvgZBEY8Pvve@B3wNpeJyYsqveriw4EdQf5PvyzgiCJXMfoMZK8E/Ykf5GBSMiVk/TYolCYF@/O7oQRLVPjHqqBdj4/10TlVL7LpwKNXAW0sQVw@r4Bzc3d4EcRFs32xlRP9cSbDto2GpTem3hbIB13VX4od3@jRrax3YMC9B/ZjPhV70PjXQqkn9HjA2qFnNyxc)

### <s>132</s> <s>122</s> <s>110</s> <s>109</s> <s>104</s> 103 bytes

```cs
_=>"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Select((c,i)=>string.Join(""+c,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Take(i))+c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/PTgIxEMbvfYrJntqAfYGFTXQFBEHRRVFvdRx1Ymlj2yUxhGdfaozRePA4@f7M98N4hD5Q10Z2L9B8xESbUvy@dO2tJUzsXdQTchQY/zjm7N5LgdbECMudiMkkRhi3DgfTkWs3FMyjpUFMIYeqCppkONQmEgyhk2pYFccn9eloPDmbzs7ni4vL5dV1s7q5Xd/dPxS6oc/3UmKfs/WrRM88O1kUPez/m12ZN5KsVA9VV4rvZVvPT7AwuUGJnXjO/AZfQW5NAM48wO5nolQK6ozuLel1yHKGzZXZpkqxF/vuAA)

- Replace `()` with `_` to show that we declare an unused variable. Thank you Kevin Cruijssen.

Comment: You can also reduce it to 90 bytes by using an [empty unused parameter](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding) like I did in my Java answer. So `o=>{...}` instead of `()=>{...}`. [Try it online: **90 bytes**.](https://tio.run/##XY7BSgMxFEX3@YrHbJoQDbqUNKVlFkJRFGbhOr5GfW1MbPI6IGW@fQxuKi7v5R7OxXqNuYT5VCm9w/BdOXxa8TeZPscYkCmnau5DCoXw3@KB0tEKjL5WeD4LgMqeCWHzSy2fXveNX8HAnkrvawAH8@hW59EXYNd19i0XiR8toVusF1ZrXN7dWtYOVd@0OQbzUohDEwVZuTS32WZKEnXXXbEZDvQlb5TSqOw0W3G5MGbawaNvU9VKuHyQ6RSjsq2cxDT/AA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I didnt know! Thank you!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I added this tip to [Tips for code-golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85053/15214)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
ØAż€Ð€`F€µJ’Ḥ»1ż@¹ḣ/€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMejex41rTk8AUgkuAGJQ1u9HjXMfLhjyaHdhkf3OBza@XDHYn2geOT//wA)

How it works:

```
                       take argument implicitly
ØA                     the uppercase alphabet
    Ð€`                for C in the alphabet
  ż€                     appends C to every letter in the alphabet
       F€              flatten every sublist
          J            get indices
           ’           subtract 1
            Ḥ          and double
             »1        take max([n, 1])
         µ     ż@¹     interleave alphabet list and indices
                  ḣ/€  reduce on head() for each element
                     Y join on newline
                       implicitly output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 29 bytes

```
'A,Au©.sRí¦®RSDgÝ×Rs)ø˜.Bíø»=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf8wNWFiMWX//ydBLEF1wqkuc1LDrcKmwq5SU0Rnw53Dl1JzKcO4y5wuQsOtw7jCuz3//w)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 bytes

New method here shaves off a lot of the length.

```perl
say$,=A;say A..$,++,''for A..Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFx9bRGkgrOOrpqehoa@uoq6flF4F4kf///8svKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaAAA)

###### Old way: [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

*@DomHastings shaved off a byte*

```perl
say$.=A;say map$_.$.,A..$.++while$.!~Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFz9bRGkgr5CYWqMTrqejpOOoBSW3t8ozMnFQVPcW6qP///@UXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNAAA)

Comment: Nice solution, I've played with this a bit and managed to get a slightly different approach, but with this, you can save 1 cheeky byte using `$.!~Z` vs. `$.ne Z`!

Comment: Oh, that new answer is inspired!

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 96 bytes

```
+++++[->+++++>++>+++++++++++++>+++++++++++++<<<<]>>>.<.<[->>>+>+[-<<.+>.>>+<]>[-<+<<->>>]<<<<.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwSide3AtB0YIQFUng0QxNrZ2enZ6NkAtdjZAeWjdW1s9LTt9IAcoByQB1QFkooFKdazif3/HwA)

**Tape Layout:**

*`[Init] [Line Count] [newline] [Growing Ascii] [Repeated Ascii] [Loop 1] [Loop 2]`*

**Explanation:**

```
+++++[->+++++>++                      Sets Line counter and newline cell
    >+++++++++++++>+++++++++++++<<<<] Sets Ascii cells to 65 ('A')
>>>.<.<                               Prints first "A" and moves to Line loop
  [->>>+>+                            Increment Repeated Ascii cell in outer loop
      [-<<.+>.>>+<]>                  Increment Growing Ascii cell in inner loop,
                                         Prints both Ascii cells and Sets Loop 2
      [-<+<<->>>]                     Resets Growing cell and Loop 1
  <<<<.<]                             Prints newline and moves to next Line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 81 bytes

```
+++[[->++<<+>]>]<<,<[----<<+>>]<+<+.<+<--.>[>+>>+[-<.+<.>>>+<]>[-<+<->>]<<<<<.>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsRQDEIPZJMTiBcJWbSFQhmYRaHnT/0uxKcez37/r/f8zQCoCgEk1GpyY4W12AgibRGpkhtUMMGUI1smj@u4lIqe@QA)

Prints in lowercase

#### Explanation:

```
+++[[->++<<+>]>]  Sets up the tape as 3*2^n (3,6,12,24,48,96,192,128)
<<,               Removes excess 128
<[----<<+>>]      Adds 196/4 to 48 resulting in 96
<+<+.             Add 1 to both 96s and print A
<+<--.            Add 1 to 25, subtract 2 from 12 to print a newline
                  Tape: 3 6 10 25 96 96 0 0
>[ Start loop
   >+>>+          Add one to the unchanging ASCII and the inner loop counter
   [-<.+<.>>>+<]  Print row while preserving counter
   >[-<+<->>]     Undo changes to changing ASCII and return inner loop counter to its cell
   <<<<<.>-       Print newline and decrement loop counter
]
```

Comment: This is really short but needs a specific interpreter with the following features:
- negative pointer or pointer wrapping
- cell wrapping
- cell size 8 bits
- end of input = 0

If the interpreter doesn't support any of these, it will produce garbish

Comment: @Dorian Generally, any type of interpreter that exists is valid on this site (though most I've seen have used the described specifications) . I will be sure to include which interpreter type I'm using in future answers though thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 88 bytes

```
++++++++[->+++>+>++++++++>++++++++<<<<]>+>++>+.<.<[->>+>>+[-<+.<.>>>+<]>[-<+<->>]<<<<.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwqide2ApJ22HUwAzrABgliwhJ22no2eDVAlkGcH1GED4tsBmUB5EM8GKBMLUq5nE/v/PwA)

should run on all brainfuck interpreters. No wrapping or negative values, no undefined input behaviour, values between 0 and 90.

**How it works**

```
Initialize tape: 25(row count) 10(lf) 64(row letter) 64(col letter) 0(col count) 0(temp)
++++++++[->+++>+>++++++++>++++++++<<<<]>+>++ 

>+.<.            print "A" and lf
<[               for each letter count
  -                decrement letter count
  >>+              increment row letter
  >>+              increment col count
  [                do col count times
    -                decrement col count
    <+.              increment and print col letter
    <.               print row letter
    >>>+             move col count to temp
    <                return to colcount
  ]
  >[-<+<->>]       move value from temp back to col count and set col letter back to "A" minus 1
  <<<<.            print lf
  <                return to row count
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish~, 4152 bytes

```
{i}cc{iiiii}iiiiic{ddddd}dddddc{iiiii}iiiiicic{ddddd}ddddddc{iiiii}iiiiiciicdcic{dddddd}iiic{iiiii}iiiiiciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}iic{iiiii}iiiiiciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}ic{iiiii}iiiiiciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}c{iiiii}iiiiiciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}dc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}dddc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}ddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}dddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{dddddd}ddddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}iiic{iiiii}iiiiic{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}iic{iiiii}iiiiic{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}ic{iiiii}iiiiic{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}c{iiiii}iiiiic{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}dc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}ddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}dddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}ddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}c{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}dddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}ic{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}iii}ddddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iic{dd}dc{ii}ic{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}ii}iiic{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiic{dd}ddc{ii}iic{dd}dc{ii}ic{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}ii}iic{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiic{dd}dddc{ii}iiic{dd}ddc{ii}iic{dd}dc{ii}ic{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}ii}ic{iiiii}iiiiic{ii}iiiiic{dd}ddddc{ii}iiiic{dd}dddc{ii}iiic{dd}ddc{ii}iic{dd}dc{ii}ic{dd}c{ii}c{dd}ic{ii}dc{dd}iic{ii}ddc{dd}iiic{ii}dddc{d}ddddddc{i}iiiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddc{i}iiiic{d}dddc{i}iiic{d}ddc{i}iic{d}dc{i}ic{d}c{i}c{d}ic{i}dc{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicdddddciiiiicddddciiiicdddciiicddciicdcic{{d}ii}c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZZLDoMwDERP1ENVmVbNusvIZ0@JkyDAg/pR@cOCBZ7YM08EgtsVd/98XGIMXpwLPl2idxeQLtF7v9KvDYveoVVAtFO/3ghgZUaVZBiTW7XK8W4hWZcX4osmg8QNuqRFp80PPVnTpip/nEBG5AnTTLPjdML0c@3gVJc5HRAL6gGzuclN7P4L5Vl55ZbzxWwVX1iNS2qyusRKXXPTrWtsJYfZRLlp6OyxzUaj2dI3RPYXlWUtUXcenCTPUQ8FgVDQ36UcFggjkpHg0HjYcaX6qmfkk1QhRUFVUjjJjZLj4FpyOFl@zNLF@AI)

Comment: Nice! Looks like the python interpreter exceeds the recursion depth but it looks like this would work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ØA¹Ƥ+"¹Ṗ€Yṭ”A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//w5hBwrnGpCsiwrnhuZbigqxZ4bmt4oCdQf//)

## Explanation

```
ØA¹Ƥ+"¹Ṗ€Yṭ”A  Main Link
ØA              Uppercase Alphabet
  ¹Ƥ            Prefixes
    +"¹         Doubly-vectorized addition to identity (uppercase alphabet) (gives lists of lists of strings)
       Ṗ€      a[:-1] of each (get rid of the double letters at the end)
         Y     Join on newlines
          ṭ”A  "A" + the result
```

partially abuses the way strings and character lists differ in Jelly

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: @tfbninja ehhh, 11 mins is ok for Jelly. thanks though :P

Comment: You can replace your second `ØA` with `¹` (like Dennis's)

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØA;\;€Ṫ$€YFḊ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDEfrGOtHTWse7lylAqQi3R7u6Pr/HwA)**

Bah just got `ØAjṪ$ƤżØAY` which is a step between this and the already posted solution of Dennis :/

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 13 bytes

```
+\ajmPjedd._G
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%5CajmPjedd._G&debug=0), [Alternative](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2BjedPded._G&debug=0)

That leading `a` though...

Comment: Good morning :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan Morning bro :p You and your inside jokes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>92</s> <s>86</s> <s>79</s> <s>75</s> 64 bytes

```python
s=map(chr,range(65,91))
for d in s:print d.join(s[:ord(d)-65])+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2N7FAIzmjSKcoMS89VcPMVMfSUFOTKy2/SCFFITNPodiqoCgzr0QhRS8rPzNPozjaKr8oRSNFU9fMNFZTO@X/fwA)

11 bytes thx to Rod.

Comment: [you don't need to use `'\n'.join(..)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2N7FAIzmjSKcoMS89VcPMVMfSUFOTKy2/SCFFITNPodiqoCgzr0QhRS8rPzNPozjaKr8oRSNFU9fMNFZTO@X/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 51 bytes

```
⍎∊'a←⎕av[65+⍳26]⋄a[n←1]',25⍴⊂'⋄,⊃a[⍳n-1],¨a[n←n+1]'
```

Explanation:

```
a←⎕av[65+⍳26] create a vector of upper case letters

a[n←1] first A

25⍴⊂'⋄,⊃a[⍳n-1],¨a[n←n+1]' create an implicit loop to concatenate subsequent letters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 47 bytes

```
d2*:1-v
-&$:?!\$:&$:1
1-:?!v\69*-$1-:
+*88~< 1o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P8VIy8pQt4xLV03Fyl4xRsUKSBtyGeoCOWUxZpZauipANpe2loVFnY2CYf7//wA)

#### How It Works:

```
d2*:1-v Initialise the stack with 26 (outer loop counter) and 26-1 (inner loop counter)
....
....
....

....
-&$:?!\$:&$:1 Repeatedly make copies of both counters
....          And decrement the inner loop counter
....          Go to third line when inner loop counter is 0

....            Add -54 to the stack (for the newline) and decrement the outer loop counter
....            Initialise the inner loop counter as outer-1
1-:?!v\69*-$1-: If the inner counter is 0, go to the fourth line, else back to the second.
....

....
....      
....      Transform numbers and -54s into letters and newlines by adding 64
+*88~< 1o Output each character until it runs out of stack and errors
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ｛Ｚ²╷ｍ¹＊×］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjVCJXVGRjNBJUIyJXUyNTc3JXVGRjREJUI5JXVGRjBBJUQ3JXVGRjNE,v=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>38, 33</strike> 30 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Bolce Bussiere

-3 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog

```
'A ',}.(}:,@,.{:)\(65+i.26){a.
```

### How?

`(65+i.26){a.` - uppercase alphabet

`\` - prefixes

`(}:,@,.{:)` - drops the last letter from each prefix and inserts it between the remaining letters

`}.` drops the leading row since it's empty (not "A")

`,` - append

`'A '`  - "A"

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfbmulYKAAxP/VHRXUdWr1NGqtdBx09KqtNGM0zEy1M/WMzDSrE/X@a3KlKQDVKukp6CjUWimkc6UmZ@QrpP0HAA)

Comment: You can use `(,.'A')` instead of `('A',49$' ')` :)

Comment: @Bolce Bussiere Thanks, it's much better now!

Comment: Just append `'A '` [TIO](https://tio.run/##y/qfbmulYKAAxP/VHRXUdWr1NGqtdBx09KqtNGM0zEy1M/WMzDSrE/X@a3KlKQDVKukp6CjUWimkc6UmZ@QrpP0HAA)

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thanks! I didn't know it works. Only the space is used as a fill?

Comment: @GalenIvanov The space is the default fill, it doesn’t come from the `'A '`.

Comment: @FrownyFrog I think I got it: 'A' is an atom, so it would be repeated to match the length of the 1-cells, resulting in a list of 50 As. 'A ' is a list, so it's filled with spaces to match the length.

Comment: @GalenIvanov Yes, that’s why `(,'A')` instead of `(,.'A')` also works.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU M4, 119 bytes

The worst so far. Well, time's already spent…

```
define(f,`ifelse($1,$2,,`format(%c%c,$1,$2)`'f(incr($1),$2)')')define(g,`f(65,$1)ifelse($1,90,,`
g(incr($1))')')A
g(66)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
Γ·:mhSzJḣ…"AZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zkQ9utcjOCq7we7lj8qGGZkmPU//8A)

#### Explanation

This leading `A` really messes things up -.-

```
          "AZ  -- string literal: "AZ"
         …     -- fill gaps: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
     S         -- with alphabet and
        ḣ      -- | alphabet rangified: ["A","AB","ABC",…,"AB……XYZ"]
      zJ       -- : zipWith join: ["A","ABB","ACBCC","ADBDCDD",…,"AZB……ZYZZ"]
Γ              -- pattern match (x:xs) with the following function (x is "A" and xs ["ABB","ACBCC",…,"A……ZYZZ"]
 · mh          -- | drop the last element of each element of xs: ["AB","ACBC",…,"A……ZYZ"]
  :            -- | cons (construct list): ["A","AB","ACBC",…,"A……ZYZ"]
               -- : strings are printed implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html), 121 bytes

I know there are better approaches but wanted to try it :)

```java
q->{String s="";for(int i=0;i<26;i++){for(int j=0;j<((i<1)?1:i*2);j++){s+=(char)((j%2!=0?i:j/2)+65);}s+="\n";}return s;}
```

ungolfed:

```java
static String d(){
    String s="";
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){      //Loop for each line
        for(int j=0;j<((i<1)?1:i*2);j++){ //Loop to create the "word"
            s+=(char)((j%2!=0?i:j/2)+65);
        }
        s+="\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY/BasMwEETv/YrFUJCq2o0NzSFrJV/QXAK5tD2oipKs6shGkg0l@NtdmRh2DzszLG@sGlTedsbZ0@@kGxUCfChy9ycActH4s9IG9vMJcIie3AU0O7Z0goFjUse0aUJUkTTswYGEaci39yUcZJbhufUsfQOSeflqUQiqqzUGIbMvl/HZtXKFtmZUl7tyQy8VRysETwmmr8pzxuxztV3taGPfKi7W7xy9ib13EHCc8MHQ9T9NYlhQhpnxlqqwB8nnt@JLjb8Qza1o@1h0yYnMFZq5vmn40mic/gE "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>130</strike> 122 bytes

```
prin"A"repeat n 26[b: copy/part"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"n
foreach d copy/part b back tail b[prin d prin last b]print""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHfu/oCgzT8lRqSi1IDWxRCFPwcgsOslKITm/oFK/ILGoRMnRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIySimPKy2/KDUxOUMhBaFBIUkhKTE5W6EkMTNHISkaZDxQGkzlJBYDpWNB7BIlpdj//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 132 bytes

```fs
let x=['A'..'Z']|>Seq.map(fun c->(+)(['A'..'Z']|>Seq.take((int c)-65)|>Seq.map(fun s->string s)|>String.concat(string c))(string c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5Pa8JAFMS/yrIgeY8km5O9ZcHa@q9Wq7G2tYqEx0aW6iZmt@DB7x4N9VA9eBvmNzNMZkPKS1VFEVvHkrce20/PnW6vP3gZvo7Gb5NpMnuff3x@LbhI1FaRA6BAYyytK7XZiEGuDXDuU3C3O0t/FGhEn7DaKscO8bfX8oTwFt7qKBO1F7u0gOzXMAol@Ai32NUDoI1jhOFDE69LNrz8YbYmf9coN5Q6uABC/Cerw02M8aXhR1mcLZcx3rC8OgE)

A naive port of my C# answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 51 bytes

```perl6
.say for 'A',{join |('A'..'Z')[++$,^++$ ],''}.../Z/
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@vOLFSIS2/SEHdUV2nOis/M0@hRgPI1tNTj1LXjNbWVtGJAxIKsTrq6rV6enr6Ufr//wMA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
.say     # print with trailing newline

  for    # each of the following

    # start the sequence
    'A',

    # code used to generate the rest of the sequence
    {
      join
        | # flatten arguments

        ( 'A' .. 'Z' )[  # Range of characters
          ++$,           # auto incrementing anon state var (value used to join)
          ^++$           # Range upto an incrementing anon
        ],
        ''               # an empty string so that the joiner is added to end
    }

    ...  # keep doing that until
    /Z/  # there is a "Z" in the value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 80 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console

```
0?"A":ForI=65To89:ForJ=65ToI:?Left$(Chr$(J),1)+Left$(Chr$(I+1),1);:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwF7JUcnKLb/I09bMNCTfwhLE9gKzPa3sfVLTSlQ0nDOKVDS8NHUMNbWRBDy1DUFC1lZ@qRUlXlb2YNrz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 77 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console.

```vb
Print"A";
For I=65 To 89
For J=65 To I
Print Chr(J)+Chr(I+1)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z@gKDOvRMlRyZrLLb9IwdPWzFQhJF/BwhLM9YJyPbnAyhScM4o0vDS1QZSntqEml19qRQlEyhrM/v8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 134 bytes

Declared function that takes no input and outputs to the console

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Dim S,I,J
S="A"
For I=65To 90
Console.WriteLine(S)
S=""
For J=65To I
S+=Chr(J)+Chr(I+1)
Next
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCoJAEEDv8xWLJ0U36lDQwYNYwUp22aCz5kADOgPuGv39lu3lvcuD9ya3dKPuO0dPzej1JCwhtDIsI6oW7NKrtiOGE03KFqZowJZJlcBFZmXKw/4u6riFWtjJiJvHTB6vxJjabA1j18TOgM3L@jWnTZavMvkugxt@fMSZB/Xb/R3/IXwB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 60 bytes

```vb
?"A"
For I=65To 89
For J=65To I?Chr$(J)+Chr$(I+1);Next
?Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/317JUYnLLb9IwdPWzDQkX8HCEszzgvA87Z0zilQ0vDS1wbSntqGmtV9qRQmXPYj8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 76 bytes

```
{for(l in 'A'..'Z'){for(c in 'A'..l){print(c)
if(c+1<l)print(l)}
println()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVXLbuM2FN3zK9hV7JnURlB0CgRpAYoiqfeL1HOnyHQsjCKpkpLMIMi3p5RsxxnUG4uXPIfnXvJcfu@mpm7ft18gHmQ5yR3cdwOcDvUIq24n4UPX7GF1KJtGtg/yFhymqR9vt9t5cp7bjFNZfZc/1BI1v6m6x@2/T3Kc6q4dtzd//nHz7Qbgrt0/jXX7AFHTH8p7OUE@lfVQlaMEgNXPsoVtB@u2f5quYfc0qf@jhLqd5DCzKWx5xvblpKKtmoSyng5ygDMRXKnP49ehHOHUwXs1VCrqcZLttIbPdQnLFpZVJfs5z9M@j3I6dLtbABBAGkBYwwDpmo51gIhGMNEJQFSjmOqUUICYxjDTGWGUAWRoBjZ0gxjUYAZApmZiUzeJSU1mGiZAlmZhS7eIRS1mGZZpAWRrNrZ1m9jUZrZhm7ZlA@RoDnZ0hzjUYY7hmI7l2A5AruZiV3eJS13mGq7pWq7tOi5AnuZhT/eIRz3mGZ7pWZ7tOZ7rAeRrPvZ1n/jUZ77hm77l277ju77nAxRoAQ70gAQ0YIERmIEV2IETuIEX@AFAoRbiUA9JSEMWGqEZWqEdOqEbeqEfBiFAkRbhSI9IRCMWGZEZWZEdOZEbeZEfBVEYAcQ1jrnOCaeccYOb3OI2d7jLPe7zgIc84gAJTWChCyKoYMIQprCELRzhCk/4IhChiAQXAMVajGM9JjGNWWzEZmzFduzEbuzFfhzEYRzFPBYxQImW4ERPSEITlhiJmViJnTiJm3iJnwRJmEQJT0QSJwClWopTPSUpTVlqpGZqpXbqpG7qpX4apGEapTwVaZwmKUCZluFMz0hGM5YZmZlZmZ05mZt5mZ8FWZhFGc9EFmdJlmYA5VqOcz0nOc1ZbuRmbuV27uRu7uV@HuRhHuU8F3mcJ3maZzlAhVbgQi9IQQtWGIVZWIVdOIVbeIVfBEVYRAUvRBEXSZEWWZEXAIihrJvZDmNfVnJUN3oHW/miQvNgkKf7Xd438hoqb7a7ctjBpuv6Q9ecluzqUfm5e5G76wW/WO1Q9r1sL8bZyd9nfyuSDs7OGg/dMCkrKsT4ojyn3Hf/UwXgS92Ov4EvWwC2W0h@9IpRuetZDqPqAbDbL@h@6JTacQP2T@15sFrDVwAgVDCqeo4sqwNs5OztmXxGnS1fV9dn0CL2CJpz3qjPuWGtLsArdLXZXBVXJ/Zf@U9yTqtbKWetXXsswUx4fYb0g2o@nxervK5hvYcvcsHNhdotpTkjPhrUrntp4X7oHo@Fm8phOm9cdc3TY/v/PVQzUlscd9os00tWqqsOZfU5seOSOTe4/BaKy7r1Kax0XoJfb@Ddifs8fwZ@jr7NktS2l6rVbT3ONdtf6nMUt4CbdjUDP2Bvyw0Q8x3ZDaqpD6enRF7ej@P5P5Z1uyqHh/EWomEof97xSfE9/HPM6rlsYA//Pp7xX9@Ot@z9VXGtml/OdwlVl8qsX0/FWIN6v6q@3tw161OW6zfwIfnt7X2hxkrTok5Jqub3ak6tVyktCc0a3/8D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
@a=A..$_,$"=pop@a,say"@a$_"for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98h0dZRT08lXkdFybYgv8AhUac4sVLJIVElXiktv0gBKBf1//@//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGAA)

I managed to get frustratingly close for 23 bytes, but the above is the shortest valid solution I've managed so far:

```perl
$,=$_,say A..$,for A..Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1YlXqc4sVLBUU9PRSctvwjEiPr//19@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQwMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
AuηćsvyS¤ý¨»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//0F1zrfEh3N2eVPCpMO9wqjCu///)

**Explanation:**

```python
Au            # Push the uppercase alphabet
  η           # Pop and push its prefixes
   ć          # Extract the head; pop and push the remainder and head
    sv        # Loop `y` over each of the remainder prefixes:
      yS      #  Convert `y` to a list of characters
        ¤     #  Push it's last character (without popping)
         ý    #  Join the characters by this character
          ¨   #  Remove the last character of the string
           »  #  And join the entire stack by newlines
              # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 63 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.875 bytes

```
n¦ƛṫv+∑∨
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJqPSIsIiIsIm7Cpsab4bmrdiviiJHiiKgiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
100001100010111101100111000011000110100000111001111001111010011
```

### Explained

```
n¦ƛṫv+∑∨­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
n¦ƛ       # ‎⁡To the prefixes of the lowercase alphabet:
   ṫv+    # ‎⁢  Add the tail to each character in (the prefix with the tail removed).
      ∑   # ‎⁣  Convert to a single string
       ∨  # ‎⁤  Special case the first a
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
!_=["A";'B':'Z'.|>i->join(('A':i-1).*i)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHeNlrJUcla3UndSj1KXa/GLlPXLis/M09DQ91R3SpT11BTTytTM/Z/SmZxQU5ipYaigeZ/AA)

function taking an unused argument and ouputing an array of strings

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 40 bytes

```sh
for c ({A..Z})<<<${(pj:$c:)s}$c&&s+=($c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVlBo9pRTy@qVtPGxkalWqMgy0ol2UqzuFYlWU2tWNtWQyVZ8/9/AA)

```sh
for c ({A..Z})             # for each character
    <<< ${(pj:$c:)s}$c &&  # print line
    #   ${(p     ) }       # - enable simple $parameters inside PE flags
    #   ${( j:$c:) }       # - join with $c
    #   ${        s}$c     # - concatenate $s with $c
    s+=($c)                # add $c to the end of the list $s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```
import StdEnv
Start=("A",[(zip2['A'..s-one][s,s..],'
')\\s<-['A'..'Z']])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4wruCSxqMRWQ8lRSSdaoyqzwCha3VFdT69YNz8vNTa6WKdYTy9WR51LXTMmpthGFyKpHqUeG6v5//@/5LScxPTi/7qePv9dKvMSczOTIRyg2T6ZSf91kwA)

This actually doesn't print a `String`, but rather a bare `(String, [([(Char, Char)], Char)])`, which is functionally the same. Unless you grab the output from this with another Clean program.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 77 bytes

```c
f(i,j){for(i=0;i<26;puts("A"+!!i++))for(j=0;j<i;)printf("%c%c",j+++65,i+65);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck7CoAwDADQ2Z5CC0JCKoigS3TwKBKopOAHP5N49lqXtzypZpEYPagL@PjtAB1q1r7peL@vE@xoqSiUCPHPkDL0yrgful4ebCmlWBeIqGudJpDfmCpfJl0BzWMyD8jmjR8)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 60 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?"A":For i=65To 89:For j=65To i:?Chr(j)Chr(i+1);:Next:?:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBasic 1.1](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack), 62 bytes

Takes no input and outputs to the STDIN

```vb
?"A"
FOR i=65TO 89
FOR j=65TO i
?CHR$(j)CHR$(i+1);
NEXT
?
NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), 36 bytes

```
\ùòGEPAí½xÑZG×í½x¹ZGË¯ÝzSHYòGËPM<¿v␄␘6Å␀ÿ
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
.>>$<_[=<4+$>_[=<.+$>._]=+>$>.<<_]@AA[␊
```

Explanation:

```
.>>$<_[=<4+$>_[=<.+$>._]=+>$>.<<_]@AA[␊
.>>$<                                   print the initial A
     _[=                        _]      loop until 2nd cell is equal to 3rd
        <4+$>                           set first cell to A
             _[=      _]=               loop until 1st cell is equal to 2nd
                <.+$>.                  print 1st cell and increment it, then print 2nd
                         +>$>.<<        increment 2nd cell and print 4th
                                  @     return
                                   AA[␊ initializer data
```