# Faux Source Code

Tags: code-golf, random, quine

Output one random character for each character of source code (as illustrated below). The probability of each character is its frequency in the original source code. Thus the output will be fake source code resembling a quine.

## Specification

- **Restrictions**

  - Standard [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) constrains apply. No empty programs or functions. Also no reading your own source.
- **Output**

  - The number of characters output should be exactly the number of characters in the source code
  - *Each* output character should be randomly choosen
  - The probability of choosing any character is equal to `(occurrences in source) / (length of source)`
  - This means that even a unary solution needs to 'randomly' choose <kbd>1</kbd> with probability `1`. Which is to say that the output can't be hard coded.
- **Winning**

  - This is code golf, so fewest bytes wins

## Example

```
Program           Frequency           Probability           Possible Output
-------           ---------           -----------           ---------------           
 a@!@              a - 1               a - 25%               @@a@
                   ! - 1               ! - 25%
                   @ - 2               @ - 50%
```

```
Program           Frequency           Probability           Possible Output
-------           ---------           -----------           ---------------
caBaDBcDaBDB       a - 3               a - 25%               aaaBBBBccDDD
                   B - 4               B - 33%
                   c - 2               c - 17%
                   D - 3               D - 25%
```

Comment: Are single-character quines allowed?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes, single character (and other unary) solutions are allowed. However, their output still needs to be randomly chosen.

Comment: How shall I find the occurences of characters in a file if I am not allowed to read it?

Comment: That is the `quine` part. Usually quines have the actual source code and a string that contains a copy of the source code. Here is a Python quine `_='_=%r;print _%%_';print _%_`

Comment: Yup, I got it from the Jelly explanation. thanks.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit my program "randomly" chooses the letter s from the set of letters "s" it is truly random too!

Comment: Is this [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Good catch! I forgot the winning criterion (－‸ლ)

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala That is a bit of a loophole. In the Specification, I was trying to outlaw solutions like that. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. `Which is to say that the output can't be hard coded.`

Comment: @NonlinearFruit so are unary quine answers unacceptable?

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala [Unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_language) solutions are welcome, that is why I chose the wording I used. But they have to conform (like everyone else) to the random criterion. Printing `s` and choosing `s` randomly from a one element set have the same result but are semantically different. This is a little nit-picky, but without it some solutions could curtail the gist of this challenge.

Comment: Is it mistake in the first example output? `@@a@` should be `@@a!`?

Comment: @VolAnd No. The *probability* of each character appearing is based on the character frequency. If you flip a coin twice and it lands on heads once, it doesn't *have* to hand on tails the second time.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I understand, it was necessary to use a random number to generate output

Comment: Is it ok to generate a random permutation of the source?

Comment: @Adam No, each output character should be chosen independently of the other output characters

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54 bytes

```perl
$_=q{print$_[rand@_]for@_="\$_=q{$_};eval"=~/./g};eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rawuqAoM69EJT66KDEvxSE@Ni2/yCHeVikGLKcSX2udWpaYo2Rbp6@nnw7h/P8PAA)

Produces output like:

```perl
_anr_;q.=fn_}v"_eo_f=n\di{nqde}[;}}o}t==@$@$=nvr$}/r=.
"q}=g{;}=[av$a}a__l[q@@;$;_}./@__a.ne=@@i_}_aet.=$=_o"
/arr_r]po{{l_=;__e"_et=="@vr__a_}@nl"ll~$=~_q~d"=v$~$/
q/@=_$__{f{vl;.]@=__=@lpapr}da@eeg_[$@lr\_{{pq$$$vrq=/
=v{[_l=p{{={/n$nv$n[_/aev_v=@on}la;}q{_otr$oaglve$.a_}
_aa;@r='{{=@{ntf;;.if}f}a$;$g/n;g;_}rroaqra=;}l.gre[t'
```

In a brief test, ~3-4% of the results of the program `eval` successfully. I'm not sure what that says about Perl...

Comment: Ahah, that comment about the 3% of successful `eval`! Nice one! ;-)

Comment: @Dada Seriously! The submissions in the answer genuinely work! I was pretty impressed...

Comment: Hopefully, from what I've seen, it just comes from the output being a entire single quoted string (with `'` or `q//`, `q{}` etc) !

Comment: @Dada Yeah, or a regex match. Made me chuckle though! :)

Comment: Happy to see you golfing again btw! :)

Answer (score 8):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 14 bytes

```
{{E*`mR}`mR}E*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e3tFKmBtUn1gbVJ9RSo&input=)

#### Explanation

Each character appears exactly twice, so the probabilities of the characters should all be the same.

```
{           e# Repeat this block 14 times.
  {E*`mR}   e# Push this (nonsensical) block.
  `         e# Stringify it, giving the string "{E*`mR}", which contains each of the
            e# seven characters once.
  mR        e# Select one of the characters at random.
}E*
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”vṾ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcO-KBvnbhub5X4bmBJFjigqzigJ124bm-&input=)

#### How it works

```
“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”vṾ  Main link. No arguments.

“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”    Set the argument and return value to the string s := ';⁾vṾWṁ$X€'.
            Ṿ  Uneval; construct a string representation of s.
               This yields r := '“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”'.
           v   Dyadic eval; evaluate s with argument r.


 ;⁾vṾWṁ$X€     Evaluated link (s). Argument: r

  ⁾vṾ          Yield 'vṾ'.
 ;             Concatenate r with 'vṾ'.
               This yields t := '“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”vṾ', i.e., the original source code.
       $       Combine the previous two links into a monadic chain.
     W           Wrap; yield ['“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”vṾ'].
      ṁ          Mold; repeat ['“;⁾vṾWṁ$X€”vṾ'] once for each charcter in t.
        X€     Random each; select a character, uniformly at random, of each
               of the 13 repetitions of t.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 bytes

```
"+Q ²£ZgMqB"+Q ²£ZgMqB
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=IitRILKjWmdNcUIiK1EgsqNaZ01xQg==&input=)

#### How it works

```
"+Q ²£ZgMqB"+Q ²£ZgMqB  // Implicit: B = 11
"+Q ²£ZgMqB"            // Take this string.
            +Q          // Append a quotation mark.
               ²        // Double the result.
                £       // Replace each char in the result Z with
                 Zg     //  the char in Z at index
                   MqB  //   random integer in the range [0, 11).
                        // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 16 Bytes

```
smO+N"m1NOs+6"16
```

[**try it online!**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smO%2BN%22m1NOs%2B6%2216&debug=0)

Contains each char twice therefore the probability is the same as if each was only in there once.

```
smO+N"m1NOs+6"16     #
   +N"m1NOs+6"       # Add a quotation mark to the string: "m1NOs+6
  O                  # random choice from the string
 m            16     # do this 16 times.
s                    # join the list into a string
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>71</s> <s>140</s> <s>110</s> <s>124</s> <s>140</s> 120 bytes

```
for($i=2*$n=strlen($s='for($i=2*$n=strlen($s=.chr(39));$i--;)echo$s[rand(0,$n-1)];'.chr(39));$i--;)echo$s[rand(0,$n-1)];
```

run with `php -d`

1. creates a string containing the code without the quotation marks
2. and concatenates the quotation mark *once* using `ord`
   (same probability as if I would double the string and add two quotes);
3. then loops over twice the length of the string to get random characters from it.

Can possibly be golfed further, but my attempts on eval where futile so far.
I will probably not go deeper here.

Comment: `The probability of each character is its frequency in the original source code.` I may be wrong, but it doesn't look like this entry meets this requirement.

Comment: Oh I missed that point. Back to the editor. How can this be done without reading the code?

Comment: Using [this](https://repl.it/languages/php), I got a `syntax error, unexpected '<'`. But I'm not familiar with PHP, how do I test this?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit: Did you use the -d flag? This is supposed to be saved to a file and then called with `php` or `php-cgi` without any flags. Maybe you can use a heredoc.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit: ... or just remove the leading `<?` for usage with `-d`.

Comment: +1 It works! (the `-cgi` did it) But I think it is outputing *142* characters instead of *140*

Comment: @NonlinearFruit: You´re right. I will debug.

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2, 88 bytes**

```
s='''from random import*; print "".join(choice(s) for c in "s='"+s+"';exec s")''';exec s
```

All *actual* merit in getting this far goes to mbomb007 - thanks for your help (and the pointer about backslashes)

Comment: This is a quine-like challenge, without input or reading your source code (suppose it is `n` characters long), you need to print `n` random characters. Where the probability of a symbol `c` being chosen is equal to `(number of times c occurs in your solution) / n`.

Comment: So more like this?

`exec("""s = 'from random import choice; print "".join([choice(s) for c in s])'; exec(s)""")`

Comment: You haven't included the single quotes yet, and you don't need the square brackets within the `join`.

Comment: Thanks - and right, I got a little caught up in the rush of nudging closer to the solution

Comment: And you can `exec s` if you restrict yourself to Python 2. Also you haven't included `s = `.

Comment: Here you go: `s='''from random import*;print"".join(choice(s)for c in s+"s='';''exec s''")''';exec s`. I wish I'd thought of that.

Comment: +1 It works! But I'm getting a *84* character output..

Comment: @user59421 Your program is currently incorrect. Look at the differences between what you have and this: `s='''from random import*;print"".join(choice(s)for c in s+"s='';''exec s''")''';exec s`

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 47 bytes

```
eval r="47.times{$><<('eval r=%p'%r)[rand 47]}"
```

This is based on the standard `eval` quine:

```
eval r="$><<'eval r=%p'%r"
```

It's a byte longer than the shortest quine, but it's usually the better choice for generalised quines, because any computation done on the source code string does not need to be duplicated. Whereas in the usual quine, every additional computation needs to go both inside and outside the main string, it is only needed inside the main string for this kind of quine.

As for what the code actually does: after obtaining a string representing the entire source code, we simply select a random character (by selecting a random index) 47 times and print each character separately.

Answer (score 3):

## Wolfram Language/Mathematica, 109 Bytes

```
Function[Print[StringJoin[RandomChoice[StringSplit[StringJoin[ToString[FullForm[Slot[0]]],"[]"],""],109]]]][]
```

sample output:

```
niPi[no,ili[Siu[,Sdoio9nthg"t ginuu[1[o]"i,icgi[0TncrS"[ln"o0]r,i][Jon[[et]0"]m [ri"a[]motrin,iFoFnultnnno,Jl
```

Oh those square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 128 bytes

```
a=";a+=uneval(a);alert(a.replace(/./g,_=>a[Math.random()*64|0]))a=";a+=uneval(a);alert(a.replace(/./g,_=>a[Math.random()*64|0]))
```

Note: only works in Firefox due to the use of `uneval`.

Sample runs:

```
)a(rgc=d6m_a4uar=hp(lll(,d=m=dee(M(gtraoan0)(M(aaaa(M]c)e)/M()/u//M6_n/a"*unea(/>atugrn(a=nav"|;)|=)/,ataa,aaangtue;am)t0;|ctoa/
=lvct;eee,,a.e=6r0;);Mtaaoa.aeea4)a[r.6]e/ll+l.)=)|a[(c"rao4ea/=_acaMh=veerva"a(_(d(l)lgn.;rM">=ea40a*).e(h(laa6r)4a)rhlar=t(ta[
[rt]ll]n))aota.e)g;>ae*;..4tt];l[;].*lnr4(mnM|alg(a.ag(.=e(a>>aa>.hga;a/pat+elc];apc=(ag)tao.).ll4u)dah]r(ul)>lr;,)ret(e/g(=_c*r
M.r)_;.a(lraalg("mac>dmrlr"0/ah(a()ead|/0a(m.|u0)(a(0_[dn)a]/raal;eata)a.ataeaa*l)=ra()la=(a)*aaea>n;.a.)ca)orM(tm*a,a=)p;(>r)aa
```

Comment: I'm now really surprised that this produced more valid code in Perl than it appears it would in JS! Not as many fun words here, except `gtraoan` which is nearly a groan I guess...

Comment: @DomHastings Well, Perl is more of a mash of punctuation than JS ;)

Comment: Definitely! It's more of a mess of punctuation than an explosion in a punctuation factory! but I quite like that!

Comment: Does `"` have a probability of showing up?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Yup. There's at least one in the first, second, and last example outputs.

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 44 bytes

I hope I have interpreted all the rules correctly (I'm not *quite* sure what the "carry payload" thing is in meta or if it's even relevant to this challenge).

```
“ẋ2;8220Ọ;8221ỌXµ44Ð¡Ḋ”ẋ2;8220Ọ;8221ỌXµ44Ð¡Ḋ
```

Test it out at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCc4bqLMjs4MjIw4buMOzgyMjHhu4xYwrU0NMOQwqHhuIrigJ3huosyOzgyMjDhu4w7ODIyMeG7jFjCtTQ0w5DCoeG4ig&input=)

This constructs a string from which to choose characters. The initial string has all the character used *except* the open and close quotes. It then doubles that string and concatenates *one of each* of the open and close quotes from ordinals (hence the need to double the other characters). Lastly it repeatedly picks random characters from the composed string to the length of the program.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Oops - I updated to add a missed character from my string but did not update to 44 - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 35 bytes

```
35F\";"\\+3322 5**F;H)s"\"2*+2* H)s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=35F%5C%22%3B%22%5C%5C%2B3322+5%2a%2aF%3BH%29s%22%5C%222%2a%2B2%2a+H%29s)

To check: remove the final `H` and the resulting string contains the right number of each character (with the extra `H`)

This does NOT use a generalised quine or in fact a quine at all. It relies on being able to create a string containing all the characters in the source. It *should* be able to do it for any code but each character logarithmically increases code size. The only number of times a character is allowed in the source is 2 or 7

Answer (score 2):

**C, 125 bytes**

```
char*s="char*s;l,i;f(){l=i=strlen(s);while(i--)putchar(s[rand()%l]);}";l,i;f(){l=i=strlen(s);while(i--)putchar(s[rand()%l]);}
```

**C, 60 bytes for golfed but not quine code taking any string**

```
l,i;f(char*s){l=i=strlen(s);while(i--)putchar(s[rand()%l]);}
```

While for counting characters my solution needed 86:

```
c[256];i;f(char*s){i=256;while(*s)c[*s++]++;while(--i)while(c[i]?c[i]--:0)putchar(i);}
```

Comment: It should not? Perhaps I do not understand the rules of this quiz. My `f` takes string and prints to standard output: string can be any sequence of characters.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Probabilities not calculated but expression `rand()%LENGTH_OF_STRING` take character according to probability of that character with normal distribution provided by `rand()`. Perhaps, I do not understand `quine` approach for C....

Comment: +1 The new solution is nearly correct. `s` just needs to contain `char*s="";`. I think something like this `char*s="char*s=l,i;f(){l=i=strlen(s);while(i--)putchar(s[rand()%l]);};+''"+'""'` would do it (but I am not familiar with C).

Comment: If the answer is not valid in its current state, then it should be deleted.

Comment: @mbomb007 Could you explain your judgment and possibly provide come advice?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Maybe you can explain.

Comment: @VolAnd Your string should contain a copy of your code. `char*s="";` is part of your code but it does not show up in your string. That is to say, you had a working solution that you made into a quine, but you are not 'quining' the parts that you added to make that happen.

Comment: I have added `char*s;` in the string. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>81</s> 67 bytes

*Saved a bunch of bytes by stealing some tricks from Martin's solution*

```
s="s=%p;67.times{$><<(s%%s)[rand 67]}";67.times{$><<(s%s)[rand 67]}
```

I didn't realize that you had to randomly select every time; I thought a shuffle would do the trick. This can probably be golfed, but it's the shortest I could get it.

[Standard Ruby quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80/31541) with a few modifications so it prints out the shuffled string. I'm sad because it took like fifteen minutes to figure out the formatting quirks before I realized that I was subconsciously stealing it anyway.

I think the string shuffling can be shortened but I don't know how; I might also be able to finagle the formatting into being shorter once I put some thought into it. Help would be appreciated.

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/ClUmW2)

Comment: I think (like my CJam) answer, it's not necessary to use a standard quine as the basis. A direct port of my CJam solution gives 64 bytes: `64.times{$><<"64.times{$><<.inspect[rand 32]}".inspect[rand 32]}`

Comment: Nevermind, basing it on a standard quine is shorter, but you'll have to use the eval-based quine: `eval r="47.times{$><<('eval r=%p'%r)[rand 47]}"`

Comment: @MartinEnder That's different enough to merit its own answer, I think. If you disagree, feel free to edit it into mine, but in the mean time I'll just steal a few tricks from yours to save a few bytes in mine.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 136 bytes

```
main(a){for(a=136;a--;)rand()%68?putchar("main(a){for(a=136;a--;)rand()%68?putchar([rand()%67]):putchar(34);}"[rand()%67]):putchar(34);}
```

Example output:

```
;%7c(u)"r4-hd)nnr-%n6;6(4or(n4(6(a:=a3r-:()hp(:aa%;4rru}h;(a()3mh3rdi7));a-u36:r3on[4?p((]6n6?()-6t736unhr%:[%[[d(p:[ru)-n(6r=:](p-})8"]
```

This program outputs 136 characters randomly.

The entire source code (less " quotation marks) is contained in a string. The program determines the probability of outputting a quotation mark as 2/136, otherwise outputting one of the other 67 characters randomly.

There are two occurrences of each character in the string in the program. The probability of outputting a character from the string is 134/136. The probability of choosing a specific character in the string is 1/67. So the chance of outputting a character in the string is 134/136 * 1/67 = 2/136. There are two occurrences of each string character in the program, so there is a 1/136 probability of outputting a character for each occurrence in the program.

The order of symbols inside the string doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 174 bytes

```r
cat(sample(el(dimnames(a<-table(c("\n",el(strsplit(scan(,""),"")))))),174,T,a),sep="")
cat(sample(el(dimnames(a<-table(c("\n",el(strsplit(scan(,""),"")))))),174,T,a),sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKM4MbcgJ1UjNUcjJTM3LzE3tVgj0Ua3JDEJKJisoRSTp6QDlCsuKSouyMkEKk9OzNPQUVLSBGEw0DE0N9EJ0UnU1ClOLbAFinLRyNj//wE)

The function `sample` performs discrete random sampling. Itcan take as 4th argument a vector `prob` of probabilities. The vector `prob` does not need to be normalized (i.e. it does not need to sum to 1): here, we use a vector of counts, and `sample` does the renormalizing.

The 2 lines are identical. The 1st line does the hard work, and reads the contents of the 2nd line to get the counts of each character. So here, the vector of probabilities `a` actually sums to 87=174/2. Note the special treatment of the newline, which `scan` does not read. I can't think of a way of avoiding this without having to add more bytes to handle quotation marks.

Comment: TIO says `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : incorrect number of probabilities`

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Thanks, should work now.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>134</s> 132 bytes

I use every character in my source code within the string the correct number of times, then multiply the string by two to include itself. The program prints a random character from that string for each character in the code (the length is hard-coded.)

```python
from random import*
for i in[0]*134:print(choice("""from random import*
for i in[0]*134:print(choice(""*""2""),end='')"""*2),end='')
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/hzVgV2)

I avoided backslashes like the plague. As soon as the code contains `\n` or `\"`, you have a problem, because the string doesn't contain backslashes yet, so you have to add those also, but in a separate string multiplied by a higher number, because it takes two backslashes to represent one (`\\`).

#### Example output:

```
i(tc*"3]i o''r=,,,h34t"r
ri"](fco t)niap)t "it2nc0o  npoi3'"nto(*4 i(ido' r*4f"oi]d rm ,i"eif)m"d
m emi
dfr n*p 3*(i""r1d"dr menc hio'
```

I gotta say, it reminds me of FlogScript.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 175 bytes

```
$d='$d={0}{1}{0}{2}-join(0..174|%{3}[char[]]($d-f [char]39,$d,"`n",[char]123,[char]125)|Random{4})'
-join(0..174|%{[char[]]($d-f [char]39,$d,"`n",[char]123,[char]125)|Random})
```

Quines in PowerShell suck, because the string replacement delimiters `{}` also denote loops and whatnot, so you need to use a *bunch* of `char`s in the `-f` operator, which bloats the code.

Similar-ish to my [Quine on Every Line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57648/42963) answer. Basically we loop from `0` to `174` and each iteration re-calculate the quine `$d`, cast it as a `char`-array, and pull out a `Random` element chosen uniformly from the input. By definition, this gives probability `(occurrences in source) / (length of source)` as required. Those characters are encapsulated in parens and `-join`ed together back into a string.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\faux-souce-code.ps1
}}[${hr[`ini}}] [5i,=[]0,j2($=n4(dm]jh]jc]]7
}..j"rnj9|fn,4r]{9]('["jdh0}$rd,-f,a.c"}{h1 ]5d,),0n5|nh(]73a9da4aRi[5}a}430}}rd$,$r)-hhr%or79-R.R-`'r'aa|=1f0][|[{7}do1]$ja0 rd{h
```

(Yes, that's a newline in the output -- when a string containing a newline is `char`-array'd, the `` `n `` is treated as a character, since a `char`-array is just an array of byte codes, so it also has a 1/175th chance of being selected.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 20 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
f←{(,⎕CR'f')[?⍴⍨20]}
```

`f←{`...`}` define **f** as

`(,⎕CR'f')` listified (`,`) **C**haracter (table) **R**epresentation (`⎕CR`) of **f** (`'f'`)

`[?⍴⍨20]` indexed with (`[`...`]`) random-up-to (`?`) repeat-itself-times (`⍴⍨`) of twenty

Let us run it (with a dummy argument) a few times:

```apl
      f⍬
)0'0](⍨(([],}⎕))⎕'f2
      f⍬
{'['}f[←R[)2←?}⍨]}C2
      f⍬
,,⍨←?2}⍴?'⍨}C,'{⎕(C0
```

Fine, but is the distribution correct? Let us run it on 10,000 dummy arguments and see how many times each character occurs:

```apl
      {⍺ , 1E¯4× ⍴⍵}⌸ ∊ f¨ ⍳1E4
C 0.9952
⎕ 0.9996
' 1.9777
f 2.004 
← 1.0018
⍨ 1.0173
0 1.0213
] 1.0049
[ 0.9988
2 0.9943
{ 0.9895
) 1.0093
R 1.0054
, 1.0029
? 0.9943
} 0.9861
⍴ 1.0032
( 0.9944
```

Clearly, `f` and `'` occur twice as often as the other characters, just like in the original source code.

How did we do it?

```apl
{⍺ , 1E¯4× ⍴⍵}⌸ ∊ f¨ ⍳1E4`
```

`⍳1E4` generates the first 10,000 integers

`f¨` runs **f** on each of those numbers

`∊` flattens all the pseudo-quines into a single 200,000-character string

`⌸` is a higher-order function which for each unique character in the right side  data, feeds the left-side function the unique element as left-argument and the indices where that character occurs as right-argument. The left-side function is

```apl
{⍺ , 1E¯4× ⍴⍵}
```

`⍺` left-argument, i.e. the unique character

`,` followed by

`1E¯4×` 1×10⁻⁴ times

`⍴⍵` the shape of the right-argument (the occurrence indices), i.e.how many times it occurs

Finally, `⌸` puts it all together in a table.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>277</s> <s>280</s> 268 bytes.

```
using System;class a{static void Main(){var s="using System;class a{static void Main(){var s=\"x5Cx5C\x5C\x5C\";Random d=new Random();for(int i=0;i++<268;)Console.Write(s[d.Next(0,134)]);}}";Random d=new Random();for(int i=0;i++<268;)Console.Write(s[d.Next(0,134)]);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System;
class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var s="using System;class a{static void Main(){var s=\"x5Cx5C\x5C\x5C\";Random d=new Random();for(int i=0;i++<268;)Console.Write(s[d.Next(0,134)]);}}";
        Random d=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i++<268;)
            Console.Write(s[d.Next(0,134)]);
    }
}
```

Pretty sure this works correctly.

Sample output:

```
    fn;i)(]ns;<ftt08et]i+ii8]m[W}dr{rmte,)t edayid 2s cmsee\;ta["e n;o}]iolys;t sftoR{.=g vs8;(sd isWrecn++iia]iuf"avs\i<{ee vfs[ensin\s i]0a(We.0ns R(2roo=ldxil\{t(o"aistt.;.  r w"m1];idi}Ctitiindnn;M[,[+0(,o"]mca[rmnm)<;n"8ReaystinRsanr([(d,n\.ateiR sd.=[=;ttn.;wna)cCt[=+t{Wxs(\}rg
```

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Thanks, missed that space.  Also means I can't use a foreach loop which adds a few bytes :(.  However, I think I do have " included correctly with those two escaped quotes in the string, since they appear in the output a few times, unless I'm missing their use somewhere else.

Comment: Ahh, I thought they didn't count if they were in the string, my bad.  Will fix in a bit.

Comment: Okay, \'s now appear as well!

Comment: Hm, interesting problem then.  Can't just keep adding \\ or I'll always be one short.  I'll use the ascii code for \ instead.

Comment: Does `(new Random()).Next(0,134)]` work? It would save a couple bytes.

Comment: It appears as though a new random class each iteration uses the same seed multiple times resulting in non-random output (the same character the entire time).

Comment: Would `var d` works? I think you can get gain 6 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 50 bytes

```julia
(a=:(print.(rand("(a=:($(a)))|>eval", 50))))|>eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBLTsMwEN37FCPDwpZCSRbdRHJvwCpLQMiKp8GVcaKx03bBATgLx@IiwU6VqCCEF6P5@H1mDqOzujpPQZE@cc4noVUtBrI@bgRpbwSfO7dCSynfd3jUjhewLeVaTgn2WNXozV31DDdA@NYfESJp66zvIAVkbKZ0XgTJGvWAUW8GTQFzvYwky3Si@b/DDO716OJLiKYfIyi4JEyQKeBEMnUIjSVslz8Zte8JLFgPVV2VZckgvYU8WWfsN@anjGSt65PdxM8uqoTazJJNTN46ya49rmrh6@Mzm8tyy9wWwEHtIN2R@jGduE0xCqWElUXWunfou/gqcl6AsZ2NQW1Typ8i4Hmo/4aGFRiuYfN@0zc)

based on this quine:

```julia
(a=:(print("(a=:($(a)))|>eval")))|>eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XyPR1kqjoCgzr0RDCcxW0UjU1NSssUstS8xRgrP@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 136 bytes

```r
a=scan(,"");cat(intToUtf8(sample(rep(c(10,utf8ToInt(a)),2),136,T)))
a=scan(,"");cat(intToUtf8(sample(rep(c(10,utf8ToInt(a)),2),136,T)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2ODkxT0NHSUnTOjmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUKjODG3ICdVoyi1QCNZw9BApxQoGJLvmVeikaipqWOkqWNobKYToqmpyUUNM/7/BwA)

The "read-a-second-copy-and-sample-from-it" approach is shamefully copied from [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231716/95126): please upvote that one.

Here, however, rather than counting the instances of each character and using this to weight the sampling, we just sample uniformly from the full set of characters (including repetitions).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 75 bytes

```python
exec(a:='from random import*;print(*choices("exec(a:=%r)"%a,k=75),sep="")')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWPa0oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VoWRcUZeaVaGglZ@RnJqcWayjBFKsWaSqpJupk25qbauoUpxbYKilpqmv@/w8A)