# hackertyper.net

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

[hackertyper.net](http://hackertyper.net/) is a website that simulates "hacking" (as the media portrays it) by outputting complicated code from the crypto section of the Linux kernel onto the screen as you type at a rate of 3 characters per one inputted.

## Challenge

Your program/function should either accept a file as a command-line argument, have the file path hard-coded, or accept the text [that would be in the file] as a command-line or function argument, and mimic [hackertyper.net](http://hackertyper.net) by outputting 3 characters onto the screen (STDOUT or equivalent) from the file for each one received through STDIN or equivalent.

Once EOF is reached, the program should start outputting characters from the beginning of the file again (wrap).

## Specs

For the purposes of simplicity, you can assume that STDIN has already been set to no buffer and no echo mode, that is not waiting until the user presses enter before passing input to your program and not displaying the characters you type.

The file can contain newlines, while the input will **not contain newlines**.

For a small example written in C (not golfed) that demonstrates how this works, see [this](http://pastie.org/10818441).

Green text and a black background are not required.

## Example input and output

The file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { }
```

Input:

```
hello world
```

Output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { }
```

---

The file:

```
hello
```

Input:

```
hello world
```

Output:

```
hellohellohellohellohellohellohel
```

Comment: 1. Are functions allowed (that take two strings as an argument and return another string)? 2. Your spec says to output three characters for every input, but the examples only output one for every input.

Comment: @Doorknob 1. Yes, and 2. That was a mistake, fixed.

Comment: Do we *have* to take the file information in as a file, or can we also receive that information through a function argument or equivalent? If we have to, what will the name of that file be? Will it be in a specific directory away from our script(s), or in the same one as our script(s)?

Comment: @R.Kap `Your program/function should either accept a file as a command-line argument or have it hard-coded`.  File isn't nessacary.

Comment: @R.Kap No, it does not *have* to be through a file. If it is, you can name it anything you like & put it anywhere you like, or accept it as a command-line argument.

Comment: @R.Kap Made an edit which I think will make this more clear.

Comment: @Majora320 ah I can't believe someone actually made that website =/ ...

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37333/8478)

Comment: [Bonuses be bad.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/51443) And plus very few people will get the penalty, and calling it a "bonus" is confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẋ3ṁ@
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bqLM-G5gUA&input=&args=J2hlbGxvIHdvcmxkJw+J2hlbGxvJw)

#### How it works

```
ẋ3ṁ@    Main link. Arguments: s (input string), t (file string)

ẋ3      Repeat s three times.
  ṁ@    Mold; reshape t like the previous result.
        This repeats the elements of t over and over until the length matches that
        of s repeated thrice.
```

Comment: I've always wondered what "mold" means...

Comment: @KennyLau I think it means it's time to throw out the bread.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.5, <strike>77</strike> <strike>65</strike> 63 bytes:

```
lambda g,f:''.join((g*len(f))[i:i+3]for i in range(0,len(f)*3,3))
```

Simple enough. An anonymous function which takes in two arguments, the first one being the "file" (`g`), and the second being the characters typed in by the user (`f`). Then this creates a generator containing every three characters in `g`, which are found by indexing for every `i` and then `i+3` characters in `g`, where `i` is in the range of `0=>(length of f)*3`. Finally, it returns each object in the generator joined into one big string. You call this function by assigning a variable to it, and then calling the variable wrapped inside a `print()` expression. So if the function's name was `q`, it would be executed like `print(q(<byte array here>))`.

[Try it online! (repl.it)](https://repl.it/CLjL/0)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://tryj.tk), 7 bytes

```
$~(3*#)
```

Takes two arguments, the text to be repeated and the user's input text.

### Usage

The input text is formatted where `,` means to join and `LF` is the newline character.

```
   f =: $~(3*#)
   ('#include <stdio.h>', LF, 'int main() { }') f 'hello world'
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { }
   'hello' f 'hello world'
hellohellohellohellohellohellohel
```

[Try it online. (tryj.tk)](http://tryj.tk)

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
⁴L×3
ẋ¢ḣ¢
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG0TMOXMwrhuovCouG4o8Ki&input=&args=ImhlbGxvIg+ImhlbGxvIHdvcmxkIg)

```
⁴L×3     Define nilad as ¢:

 L       length of
⁴        second argument
  ×3     tripled


ẋ¢ḣ¢     Main chain:
       
         the first argument (implicit)
ẋ        repeated
 ¢       ¢ many times
  ḣ¢     then get the first ¢ characters of it.
```

Comment: I guess you're a bit "jelly" of Dennis' answer?

Comment: Jelly is evil..

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
s@Ljb.z*3l
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%40Ljb.z*3l&input=%22hello+world%22%0Ahello&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```
(s,t)=>s.repeat(l=t.length*3).slice(0,l)
```

Where `s` is the data string and `t` is the user string. Assumes `s` is nonempty and repeats it `l` times to ensure that its length is at least `l` so that it can return the first `l` characters, where `l` is three times the length of `t`.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 25 bytes

First argument is what's "typed", the second the source to display

```
(.cycle).take.(3*).length
```

Or non-pointfree, for (possibly) better readability:

```
h a=take(3*length a).cycle
```

Comment: What's `cycle`?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy `cycle` takes a list and repeats it infinitely. Eg `cycle "hi" == "hihihihi..`

Comment: Have you considered `$`?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I'm not sure where I'd use it, what were you thinking?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Code:

```
3×g©×®£
```

Explanation:

```
3×        # Multiply the input string three times.
  g       # Take the length.
   ©      # Copy that to the register.
    ×     # Multiply by the second input.
     ®    # Retrieve the length from the register.
      £   # Only keep [0:length * 3] from the new string.
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=M8OXZ8Kpw5fCrsKj&input=aGVsbG8gd29ybGQKaGVsbG8).

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 10 bytes

```
]*iγl*I30γ
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=XSppzrNsKkkzMM6z)

### Explanation

```
]*iγl*I30γ
 *i        repeat string 1
    l*I3    the length of the other string * 3
   γ        γ = (^)
]       0γ  (^).slice(0, γ)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 39 bytes

In Ruby, `$<` reads from the supplied file in the command line arguments instead of `$stdin` if one is given. (If you forget to supply a file, you get a blank output because it reads everything out of `$stdin` in `$<.read` and thus `STDIN.read.size` will be 0.)

```
$><<($<.read*s=3*STDIN.read.size)[0,s]
```